# LINQ - Full Outer Join

Tags: c#, .net, linq, outer-join, full-outer-join

I have a list of people's ID and their first name, and a list of people's ID and their surname. Some people don't have a first name and some don't have a surname; I'd like to do a full outer join on the two lists.

So the following lists:

```
ID  FirstName
--  ---------
 1  John
 2  Sue

ID  LastName
--  --------
 1  Doe
 3  Smith
```

Should produce:

```
ID  FirstName  LastName
--  ---------  --------
 1  John       Doe
 2  Sue
 3             Smith
```

I have found quite a few solutions for 'LINQ Outer Joins' which all look quite similar, but really seem to be left outer joins.

My attempts so far go something like this:

```
private void OuterJoinTest()
{
    List<FirstName> firstNames = new List<FirstName>();
    firstNames.Add(new FirstName { ID = 1, Name = "John" });
    firstNames.Add(new FirstName { ID = 2, Name = "Sue" });

    List<LastName> lastNames = new List<LastName>();
    lastNames.Add(new LastName { ID = 1, Name = "Doe" });
    lastNames.Add(new LastName { ID = 3, Name = "Smith" });

    var outerJoin = from first in firstNames
        join last in lastNames
        on first.ID equals last.ID
        into temp
        from last in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new
        {
            id = first != null ? first.ID : last.ID,
            firstname = first != null ? first.Name : string.Empty,
            surname = last != null ? last.Name : string.Empty
        };
    }
}

public class FirstName
{
    public int ID;
    
    public string Name;
}
    
public class LastName
{
    public int ID;
    
    public string Name;
}
```

But this returns:

```
ID  FirstName  LastName
--  ---------  --------
 1  John       Doe
 2  Sue
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you need this to work for in-memory lists only, or for Linq2Sql?

Comment: Try .GroupJoin() https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595289/linq-to-entities-join-vs-groupjoin

Answer (score 140, accepted):

I don't know if this covers all cases, logically it seems correct. The idea is to take a left outer join and right outer join then take the union of the results.

```
var firstNames = new[]
{
    new { ID = 1, Name = "John" },
    new { ID = 2, Name = "Sue" },
};
var lastNames = new[]
{
    new { ID = 1, Name = "Doe" },
    new { ID = 3, Name = "Smith" },
};
var leftOuterJoin =
    from first in firstNames
    join last in lastNames on first.ID equals last.ID into temp
    from last in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
        first.ID,
        FirstName = first.Name,
        LastName = last?.Name,
    };
var rightOuterJoin =
    from last in lastNames
    join first in firstNames on last.ID equals first.ID into temp
    from first in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
        last.ID,
        FirstName = first?.Name,
        LastName = last.Name,
    };
var fullOuterJoin = leftOuterJoin.Union(rightOuterJoin);
```

This works as written since it is in LINQ to Objects. If LINQ to SQL or other, the query processor might not support safe navigation or other operations. You'd have to use the conditional operator to conditionally get the values.

i.e.,

```
var leftOuterJoin =
    from first in firstNames
    join last in lastNames on first.ID equals last.ID into temp
    from last in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
        first.ID,
        FirstName = first.Name,
        LastName = last != null ? last.Name : default,
    };
```

Comment: Union will eliminate duplicates.  If you are not expecting duplicates, or can write the second query to exclude anything that was included in the first, use Concat instead.  This is the SQL difference between UNION and UNION ALL

Comment: @cadre110 duplicates will occur if a person has a first name and a last name, so union is a valid choice.

Comment: @saus but there is an ID column, so even if there is a duplicate first and last name, the ID should be different

Comment: @cadrell: I don't see why you would want the duplicates here any way.  Full outer joins don't include them AFAIK.  You're not going to save anything here by using `Concat()`.  If the data was disjoint, then you might save a few cycles, but that would make the implementation not very robust and only work with only some data sets.  One might argue that it would be a premature optimization.

Comment: Your solution works for primitive types, but doesn't seem to work for objects.  In my case, FirstName is an domain object, while LastName is another domain object.  When I union the two results, LINQ threw a NotSupportedException (Types in Union or Concat are constructed incompatibly).  Have you experienced similar problems?

Comment: @CandyChiu: I actually never ran into such a case. I guess that's a limitation with your query provider. You'll probably want to use LINQ to Objects in that case by calling `AsEnumerable()` before you perform the union/concatenation. Try that and see how that goes. If this is not the route you want to go, I'm not sure I can be of any more help than that.

Comment: @cadrell0: If you use anonymous types as you have, Linq will not avoid duplicates. If you want to avoid duplicates, use a concrete type. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16980485/remove-duplicates-while-merging-lists-using-union-in-linq

Comment: @Steztric That is easily shown as incorrect, in C#. In VB you must mark all the properties as key properties.

Comment: For such a simple case, I don't think you need `temp`. You should be able to use `lastNames.DefaultIfEmpty(...)` directly.

Answer (score 242):

**Update 1: providing a truly generalized extension method `FullOuterJoin`**
**Update 2: optionally accepting a custom `IEqualityComparer` for the key type**
**Update 3**: this implementation has [***recently become part of `MoreLinq`***](https://github.com/fsateler/MoreLINQ/commit/b526df48cb7d01097115e9c00321d3bbe33ad1b6#diff-0beb3537636462a3e60cf47309d73c72R25) - Thanks guys!

**Edit** Added `FullOuterGroupJoin` ([ideone](http://ideone.com/kG4kqO)). I reused the `GetOuter<>` implementation, making this a fraction less performant than it could be, but I'm aiming for 'highlevel' code, not bleeding-edge optimized, right now.

See it live on **http://ideone.com/O36nWc**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var ax = new[] { 
        new { id = 1, name = "John" },
        new { id = 2, name = "Sue" } };
    var bx = new[] { 
        new { id = 1, surname = "Doe" },
        new { id = 3, surname = "Smith" } };

    ax.FullOuterJoin(bx, a => a.id, b => b.id, (a, b, id) => new {a, b})
        .ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
}
```

Prints the output:

```
{ a = { id = 1, name = John }, b = { id = 1, surname = Doe } }
{ a = { id = 2, name = Sue }, b =  }
{ a = , b = { id = 3, surname = Smith } }
```

You could also supply defaults: **http://ideone.com/kG4kqO**

```
    ax.FullOuterJoin(
            bx, a => a.id, b => b.id, 
            (a, b, id) => new { a.name, b.surname },
            new { id = -1, name    = "(no firstname)" },
            new { id = -2, surname = "(no surname)" }
        )
```

Printing:

```
{ name = John, surname = Doe }
{ name = Sue, surname = (no surname) }
{ name = (no firstname), surname = Smith }
```

### Explanation of terms used:

Joining is a term borrowed from relational database design:

- A **join** will repeat elements from `a` as many times as there are elements in `b` *with corresponding key* (i.e.: nothing if `b` were empty). *Database lingo calls this `inner (equi)join`*.
- An **outer join** includes elements from `a` for which *no corresponding
  element* exists in `b`. (i.e.: even results if `b` were empty). *This is usually referred to as `left join`*.
- A **full outer join** includes records from `a` *as well as `b`* if *no corresponding element* exists in the other. (i.e. even results if `a` were empty)

Something not *usually* seen in RDBMS is a group join<sup>[1]</sup>:

- A **group join**, does the same as described above, **but** instead of repeating elements from `a` for multiple corresponding `b`, it *groups* the records with corresponding keys. This is often more convenient when you wish to enumerate through 'joined' records, based on a common key.

See also [GroupJoin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupjoin.aspx) which contains some general background explanations as well.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> (I believe Oracle and MSSQL have proprietary extensions for this)

### Full code

A generalized 'drop-in' Extension class for this

```
internal static class MyExtensions
{
    internal static IEnumerable<TResult> FullOuterGroupJoin<TA, TB, TKey, TResult>(
        this IEnumerable<TA> a,
        IEnumerable<TB> b,
        Func<TA, TKey> selectKeyA, 
        Func<TB, TKey> selectKeyB,
        Func<IEnumerable<TA>, IEnumerable<TB>, TKey, TResult> projection,
        IEqualityComparer<TKey> cmp = null)
    {
        cmp = cmp?? EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default;
        var alookup = a.ToLookup(selectKeyA, cmp);
        var blookup = b.ToLookup(selectKeyB, cmp);

        var keys = new HashSet<TKey>(alookup.Select(p => p.Key), cmp);
        keys.UnionWith(blookup.Select(p => p.Key));

        var join = from key in keys
                   let xa = alookup[key]
                   let xb = blookup[key]
                   select projection(xa, xb, key);

        return join;
    }

    internal static IEnumerable<TResult> FullOuterJoin<TA, TB, TKey, TResult>(
        this IEnumerable<TA> a,
        IEnumerable<TB> b,
        Func<TA, TKey> selectKeyA, 
        Func<TB, TKey> selectKeyB,
        Func<TA, TB, TKey, TResult> projection,
        TA defaultA = default(TA), 
        TB defaultB = default(TB),
        IEqualityComparer<TKey> cmp = null)
    {
        cmp = cmp?? EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default;
        var alookup = a.ToLookup(selectKeyA, cmp);
        var blookup = b.ToLookup(selectKeyB, cmp);

        var keys = new HashSet<TKey>(alookup.Select(p => p.Key), cmp);
        keys.UnionWith(blookup.Select(p => p.Key));

        var join = from key in keys
                   from xa in alookup[key].DefaultIfEmpty(defaultA)
                   from xb in blookup[key].DefaultIfEmpty(defaultB)
                   select projection(xa, xb, key);

        return join;
    }
}
```

Comment: Edited to show the usage of the `FullOuterJoin` extension method provided

Comment: Edited: FullOuterGroupJoin extension method added

Comment: Instead of using a Dictionary, you can use a [Lookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx), which contains the functionality expressed in your helper extension methods.  For example, you can write `a.GroupBy(selectKeyA).ToDictionary();` as `a.ToLookup(selectKeyA)` and `adict.OuterGet(key)` as `alookup[key]`.  Getting the collection of keys is a little trickier, though: `alookup.Select(x => x.Keys)`.

Comment: @RiskyMartin Thanks! That, indeed, makes the whole thing more elegant. I updated the answer _and_ the ideone-s. (I suppose the performance should be increased since fewer objects are instantiated).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the example... code works great! Can you explain though what the first function, `FullOuterGroupJoin` does?

Comment: @eidylon I've added **Explanation of terms used** in my answer. Hope that helps!

Comment: How could FullOuterJoin be modified to accept (and use) and IEqualityComparer<>?

Comment: Thanks! So the ToLookup()'s do not need to use the EqualityComparer?

Comment: @Jimmy arhem <blush/> probably best if you did. [Fixed it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13503860/revisions) :)

Comment: Nice implementation, but it does not use deferred execution. I made one that uses an iterator to achieve this and added it as another answer.

Comment: This worked! As noted, does not support deferred execution (@SørenBoisen's answer also worked for me). However neither of them appears to support intellisense i.e. when entering the two arguments `selectKeyA` and `selectKeyB` I had to manually determine the valid properties and enter them. Why is this? (Just curious). Also, when I accidentally mismatched the types of the select key, the compiler error was ambiguous, stating the "types could not be inferred" rather than that they mismatched.

Comment: I couldn't get the group join function to work, but achieved the desired results using `.Group().Select()` on both data sets before doing `.FullOuterJoin()`. Sick of fighting with LINQ to avoid an ultimately trivial SQL query so I'm stopping here!

Comment: @Visser Yeah, intellisense sometimes breaks down when writing lambdas. I think Microsoft took some shortcuts there, to get the code out the door.

Comment: Am I missing something, or does MoreLinq only include the group join implementation? I can't find `FullOuterJoin` in that library.

Comment: @RuudLenders ISTR they may have renamed it, but I don't use MoreLinq so I don't really know anymore

Comment: @sehe looking at the commit, it looks like the function never was in MoreLinq to begin with.

Comment: @sehe: do you think it can be a nice idea to add also this optimization? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52206904/full-outer-join-in-linq-optimized-for-unique-keys?noredirect=1#comment91364168_52206904

Comment: @Revious that works only if you know the keys are unique. And that's not the common case for /grouping/. Other than that, yes, by all means. If you know the hash is not going to drag perf (node-based containers have more cost in principle, and hashing is not free and efficiency depends on the hash function/bucket spread), it will certainly be more algorithmically efficient. So, for small loads I'd expect it might not be quicker

Answer (score 50):

I think there are problems with most of these, including the accepted answer, because they don't work well with Linq over IQueryable either due to doing too many server round trips and too much data returns, or doing too much client execution.

For IEnumerable I don't like Sehe's answer or similar because it has excessive memory use (a simple 10000000 two list test ran Linqpad out of memory on my 32GB machine).

Also, most of the others don't actually implement a proper Full Outer Join because they are using a Union with a Right Join instead of Concat with a Right Anti Semi Join, which not only eliminates the duplicate inner join rows from the result, but any proper duplicates that existed originally in the left or right data.

So here are my extensions that handle all of these issues, generate SQL as well as implementing the join in LINQ to SQL directly, executing on the server, and is faster and with less memory than others on Enumerables:

```
public static class Ext {
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> LeftOuterJoin<TLeft, TRight, TKey, TResult>(
        this IEnumerable<TLeft> leftItems,
        IEnumerable<TRight> rightItems,
        Func<TLeft, TKey> leftKeySelector,
        Func<TRight, TKey> rightKeySelector,
        Func<TLeft, TRight, TResult> resultSelector) {

        return from left in leftItems
               join right in rightItems on leftKeySelector(left) equals rightKeySelector(right) into temp
               from right in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
               select resultSelector(left, right);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TResult> RightOuterJoin<TLeft, TRight, TKey, TResult>(
        this IEnumerable<TLeft> leftItems,
        IEnumerable<TRight> rightItems,
        Func<TLeft, TKey> leftKeySelector,
        Func<TRight, TKey> rightKeySelector,
        Func<TLeft, TRight, TResult> resultSelector) {

        return from right in rightItems
               join left in leftItems on rightKeySelector(right) equals leftKeySelector(left) into temp
               from left in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
               select resultSelector(left, right);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TResult> FullOuterJoinDistinct<TLeft, TRight, TKey, TResult>(
        this IEnumerable<TLeft> leftItems,
        IEnumerable<TRight> rightItems,
        Func<TLeft, TKey> leftKeySelector,
        Func<TRight, TKey> rightKeySelector,
        Func<TLeft, TRight, TResult> resultSelector) {

        return leftItems.LeftOuterJoin(rightItems, leftKeySelector, rightKeySelector, resultSelector).Union(leftItems.RightOuterJoin(rightItems, leftKeySelector, rightKeySelector, resultSelector));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TResult> RightAntiSemiJoin<TLeft, TRight, TKey, TResult>(
        this IEnumerable<TLeft> leftItems,
        IEnumerable<TRight> rightItems,
        Func<TLeft, TKey> leftKeySelector,
        Func<TRight, TKey> rightKeySelector,
        Func<TLeft, TRight, TResult> resultSelector) {

        var hashLK = new HashSet<TKey>(from l in leftItems select leftKeySelector(l));
        return rightItems.Where(r => !hashLK.Contains(rightKeySelector(r))).Select(r => resultSelector(default(TLeft),r));
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TResult> FullOuterJoin<TLeft, TRight, TKey, TResult>(
        this IEnumerable<TLeft> leftItems,
        IEnumerable<TRight> rightItems,
        Func<TLeft, TKey> leftKeySelector,
        Func<TRight, TKey> rightKeySelector,
        Func<TLeft, TRight, TResult> resultSelector)  where TLeft : class {

        return leftItems.LeftOuterJoin(rightItems, leftKeySelector, rightKeySelector, resultSelector).Concat(leftItems.RightAntiSemiJoin(rightItems, leftKeySelector, rightKeySelector, resultSelector));
    }

    private static Expression<Func<TP, TC, TResult>> CastSMBody<TP, TC, TResult>(LambdaExpression ex, TP unusedP, TC unusedC, TResult unusedRes) => (Expression<Func<TP, TC, TResult>>)ex;

    public static IQueryable<TResult> LeftOuterJoin<TLeft, TRight, TKey, TResult>(
        this IQueryable<TLeft> leftItems,
        IQueryable<TRight> rightItems,
        Expression<Func<TLeft, TKey>> leftKeySelector,
        Expression<Func<TRight, TKey>> rightKeySelector,
        Expression<Func<TLeft, TRight, TResult>> resultSelector) {

        var sampleAnonLR = new { left = default(TLeft), rightg = default(IEnumerable<TRight>) };
        var parmP = Expression.Parameter(sampleAnonLR.GetType(), "p");
        var parmC = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TRight), "c");
        var argLeft = Expression.PropertyOrField(parmP, "left");
        var newleftrs = CastSMBody(Expression.Lambda(Expression.Invoke(resultSelector, argLeft, parmC), parmP, parmC), sampleAnonLR, default(TRight), default(TResult));

        return leftItems.AsQueryable().GroupJoin(rightItems, leftKeySelector, rightKeySelector, (left, rightg) => new { left, rightg }).SelectMany(r => r.rightg.DefaultIfEmpty(), newleftrs);
    }

    public static IQueryable<TResult> RightOuterJoin<TLeft, TRight, TKey, TResult>(
        this IQueryable<TLeft> leftItems,
        IQueryable<TRight> rightItems,
        Expression<Func<TLeft, TKey>> leftKeySelector,
        Expression<Func<TRight, TKey>> rightKeySelector,
        Expression<Func<TLeft, TRight, TResult>> resultSelector) {

        var sampleAnonLR = new { leftg = default(IEnumerable<TLeft>), right = default(TRight) };
        var parmP = Expression.Parameter(sampleAnonLR.GetType(), "p");
        var parmC = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TLeft), "c");
        var argRight = Expression.PropertyOrField(parmP, "right");
        var newrightrs = CastSMBody(Expression.Lambda(Expression.Invoke(resultSelector, parmC, argRight), parmP, parmC), sampleAnonLR, default(TLeft), default(TResult));

        return rightItems.GroupJoin(leftItems, rightKeySelector, leftKeySelector, (right, leftg) => new { leftg, right }).SelectMany(l => l.leftg.DefaultIfEmpty(), newrightrs);
    }

    public static IQueryable<TResult> FullOuterJoinDistinct<TLeft, TRight, TKey, TResult>(
        this IQueryable<TLeft> leftItems,
        IQueryable<TRight> rightItems,
        Expression<Func<TLeft, TKey>> leftKeySelector,
        Expression<Func<TRight, TKey>> rightKeySelector,
        Expression<Func<TLeft, TRight, TResult>> resultSelector) {

        return leftItems.LeftOuterJoin(rightItems, leftKeySelector, rightKeySelector, resultSelector).Union(leftItems.RightOuterJoin(rightItems, leftKeySelector, rightKeySelector, resultSelector));
    }

    private static Expression<Func<TP, TResult>> CastSBody<TP, TResult>(LambdaExpression ex, TP unusedP, TResult unusedRes) => (Expression<Func<TP, TResult>>)ex;

    public static IQueryable<TResult> RightAntiSemiJoin<TLeft, TRight, TKey, TResult>(
        this IQueryable<TLeft> leftItems,
        IQueryable<TRight> rightItems,
        Expression<Func<TLeft, TKey>> leftKeySelector,
        Expression<Func<TRight, TKey>> rightKeySelector,
        Expression<Func<TLeft, TRight, TResult>> resultSelector) {

        var sampleAnonLgR = new { leftg = default(IEnumerable<TLeft>), right = default(TRight) };
        var parmLgR = Expression.Parameter(sampleAnonLgR.GetType(), "lgr");
        var argLeft = Expression.Constant(default(TLeft), typeof(TLeft));
        var argRight = Expression.PropertyOrField(parmLgR, "right");
        var newrightrs = CastSBody(Expression.Lambda(Expression.Invoke(resultSelector, argLeft, argRight), parmLgR), sampleAnonLgR, default(TResult));

        return rightItems.GroupJoin(leftItems, rightKeySelector, leftKeySelector, (right, leftg) => new { leftg, right }).Where(lgr => !lgr.leftg.Any()).Select(newrightrs);
    }

    public static IQueryable<TResult> FullOuterJoin<TLeft, TRight, TKey, TResult>(
        this IQueryable<TLeft> leftItems,
        IQueryable<TRight> rightItems,
        Expression<Func<TLeft, TKey>> leftKeySelector,
        Expression<Func<TRight, TKey>> rightKeySelector,
        Expression<Func<TLeft, TRight, TResult>> resultSelector) {

        return leftItems.LeftOuterJoin(rightItems, leftKeySelector, rightKeySelector, resultSelector).Concat(leftItems.RightAntiSemiJoin(rightItems, leftKeySelector, rightKeySelector, resultSelector));
    }
}
```

The difference between a Right Anti-Semi-Join is mostly moot with Linq to Objects or in the source, but makes a difference on the server (SQL) side in the final answer, removing an unnecessary `JOIN`.

The hand coding of `Expression` to handle merging an `Expression<Func<>>` into a lambda could be improved with LinqKit, but it would be nice if the language/compiler had added some help for that. The `FullOuterJoinDistinct` and `RightOuterJoin` functions are included for completeness, but I did not re-implement `FullOuterGroupJoin` yet.

I wrote [another version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50978697/2557128) of a full outer join for `IEnumerable` for cases where the key is orderable, which is about 50% faster than combining the left outer join with the right anti semi join, at least on small collections. It goes through each collection after sorting just once.

I also added [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49418695/2557128) for a version that works with EF by replacing the `Invoke` with a custom expansion.

Comment: What's the deal with `TP unusedP, TC unusedC`? Are they literally unused?

Comment: Yes, they are just present to capture the types in `TP`, `TC`, `TResult` to create the proper `Expression<Func<>>`. I supposed I could replace them with `_`, `__`, `___` instead, but that doesn't seem any clearer until C# has a proper parameter wildcard to use instead.

Comment: Thanks for this. It's only recent, so I hope this gets well-upvoted.  One of the largest use cases for LINQ is the "transparency" of being able to use extensions against either `IEnumerable` (Linq to Objects) or `IQueryable` (Linq to (SQL|Entities|what have you).  Answers that present no effort on the latter, saying "OP didn't *ask* for Linq to SQL" are tiresome.  Maybe there's a more "SO-correct" way of handling this situation, but in the meantime, search engines send us to questions like these.

Comment: @MarcL. I'm not so sure about 'tiresome' - but I agree this answer is very useful in this context. Impressive stuff (although to me it confirms the shortcomings of Linq-to-SQL)

Comment: I am getting `The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.`. Are there any restrictions with this code? I want to perform a FULL JOIN over IQueryables

Comment: @Learner Are you doing EF Core or EF 6?

Comment: @NetMage I am using EF6

Comment: I get this too, EF62, database in Azure, same result with a SQLCE database

Comment: I have added a new answer that replaces `Invoke` with a custom `ExpressionVisitor` to inline the `Invoke` so it should work with EF. Can you try it?

Comment: Hi. does anyone have a `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core` version? Since my types are not known at compile-time. Thanks!

Comment: Could you add some short examples with two list, for how to use these joins? I will find it out somehow, but for others it would be usefull.

Comment: @MikhailKh They are extension methods that work exactly the same as the LINQ built-in `Join` method: just replace `Join` with `FullOuterJoin` or `LeftOuterJoin` or `RightOuterJoin`.

Comment: yep, I get througth, but for me it was quite unusual syntaxis, and example like this might be helpful to save 20-30 minutes  
var tags = new List<Something>();
var status = new List<Something2>();
var joinResult = tags.FullOuterJoin(status, f => f.tag, k => k.Tag, (r, l) => {
        return new Something3() { id = r.id, tag = r.tag, color = l.Color, status = l.Status };}).ToList();

Comment: @MikhailKh It is exactly link the normal LINQ `Join` function - see Microsoft's examples in the C# documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=net-6.0).

Comment: Link "another version" is broken :(

Comment: @cristiancastrodc It works for me? The other answer is on this page, just search for my username.

Comment: Implementing FullOuterJoin in terms of the LeftOuterJoin and RightOuterJoin methods is elegant, but results in multiple enumerations. For forward-only streams, this will fail.

Answer (score 10):

I'm guessing @sehe's approach is stronger, but until I understand it better, I find myself leap-frogging off of @MichaelSander's extension.  I modified it to match the syntax and return type of the built-in Enumerable.Join() method described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675(v=vs.100).aspx).  I appended the "distinct" suffix in respect to @cadrell0's comment under @JeffMercado's solution.

```
public static class MyExtensions {

    public static IEnumerable<TResult> FullJoinDistinct<TLeft, TRight, TKey, TResult> (
        this IEnumerable<TLeft> leftItems, 
        IEnumerable<TRight> rightItems, 
        Func<TLeft, TKey> leftKeySelector, 
        Func<TRight, TKey> rightKeySelector,
        Func<TLeft, TRight, TResult> resultSelector
    ) {

        var leftJoin = 
            from left in leftItems
            join right in rightItems 
              on leftKeySelector(left) equals rightKeySelector(right) into temp
            from right in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select resultSelector(left, right);

        var rightJoin = 
            from right in rightItems
            join left in leftItems 
              on rightKeySelector(right) equals leftKeySelector(left) into temp
            from left in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select resultSelector(left, right);

        return leftJoin.Union(rightJoin);
    }

}
```

In the example, you would use it like this:

```
var test = 
    firstNames
    .FullJoinDistinct(
        lastNames,
        f=> f.ID,
        j=> j.ID,
        (f,j)=> new {
            ID = f == null ? j.ID : f.ID, 
            leftName = f == null ? null : f.Name,
            rightName = j == null ? null : j.Name
        }
    );
```

In the future, as I learn more, I have a feeling I'll be migrating to @sehe's logic given it's popularity.  But even then I'll have to be careful, because I feel it is important to have at least one overload that matches the syntax of the existing ".Join()" method if feasible, for two reasons:

1. Consistency in methods helps save time, avoid errors, and avoid unintended behavior.
2. If there ever is an out-of-the-box ".FullJoin()" method in the future, I would imagine it will try to keep to the syntax of the currently existing ".Join()" method if it can.  If it does, then if you want to migrate to it, you can simply rename your functions without changing the parameters or worrying about different return types breaking your code.

I'm still new with generics, extensions, Func statements, and other features, so feedback is certainly welcome.

**EDIT:** Didn't take me long to realize there was a problem with my code.  I was doing a .Dump() in LINQPad and looking at the return type.  It was just IEnumerable, so I tried to match it.  But when I actually did a .Where() or .Select() on my extension I got an error: "'System Collections.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and ...".  So in the end I was able to match the input syntax of .Join(), but not the return behavior.

**EDIT:** Added "TResult" to the return type for the function.  Missed that when reading the Microsoft article, and of course it makes sense.  With this fix, it now seems the return behavior is in line with my goals after all.

Comment: +2 for this answer as well as Michael Sanders. I accidentally clicked this down and the vote is locked. Please add two.

Comment: @TamusJRoyce, I just went in to edit the code formats a bit.  I believe after an edit is made, you have the option to recast your vote.  Give it a shot if you like.

Answer (score 9):

Here is an extension method doing that:

```
public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TLeft, TRight>> FullOuterJoin<TLeft, TRight>(this IEnumerable<TLeft> leftItems, Func<TLeft, object> leftIdSelector, IEnumerable<TRight> rightItems, Func<TRight, object> rightIdSelector)
{
    var leftOuterJoin = from left in leftItems
        join right in rightItems on leftIdSelector(left) equals rightIdSelector(right) into temp
        from right in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new { left, right };

    var rightOuterJoin = from right in rightItems
        join left in leftItems on rightIdSelector(right) equals leftIdSelector(left) into temp
        from left in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new { left, right };

    var fullOuterJoin = leftOuterJoin.Union(rightOuterJoin);

    return fullOuterJoin.Select(x => new KeyValuePair<TLeft, TRight>(x.left, x.right));
}
```

Comment: +1. R ⟗ S = (R ⟕ S) ∪ (R ⟖ S), which means a full outer join = left outer join union all right outer join! I appreciate the simplicity of this approach.

Comment: @TamusJRoyce Except `Union` removes duplicates, so if there are duplicate rows in the original data, they won't be in the result.

Comment: Great point! add a unique id if you need to prevent duplicates from being removed. Yes. The union is a bit wasteful unless you can hint that there is a unique id and the union switches to union all (via internal heuristics/optimizations). But it will work.

Comment: Same as the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5491381/861716).

Comment: How can I filter out by `Where` clause to result?

Answer (score 5):

As you've found, Linq doesn't have an "outer join" keyword construct, requiring you to use the query you stated to produce a left outer join. To this, you can add any elements of the lastname list that aren't represented in the joined collection, producing the same result set as a full join:

```
outerJoin = outerJoin.Concat(lastNames.Select(l=>new
                            {
                                id = l.ID,
                                firstname = String.Empty,
                                surname = l.Name
                            }).Where(l=>!outerJoin.Any(o=>o.id == l.id)));
```

Answer (score 5):

My clean solution for situation that key is unique in both enumerables:

```
 private static IEnumerable<TResult> FullOuterJoin<Ta, Tb, TKey, TResult>(
            IEnumerable<Ta> a, IEnumerable<Tb> b,
            Func<Ta, TKey> key_a, Func<Tb, TKey> key_b,
            Func<Ta, Tb, TResult> selector)
        {
            var alookup = a.ToLookup(key_a);
            var blookup = b.ToLookup(key_b);
            var keys = new HashSet<TKey>(alookup.Select(p => p.Key));
            keys.UnionWith(blookup.Select(p => p.Key));
            return keys.Select(key => selector(alookup[key].FirstOrDefault(), blookup[key].FirstOrDefault()));
        }
```

so

```
    var ax = new[] {
        new { id = 1, first_name = "ali" },
        new { id = 2, first_name = "mohammad" } };
    var bx = new[] {
        new { id = 1, last_name = "rezaei" },
        new { id = 3, last_name = "kazemi" } };

    var list = FullOuterJoin(ax, bx, a => a.id, b => b.id, (a, b) => "f: " + a?.first_name + " l: " + b?.last_name).ToArray();
```

outputs:

```
f: ali l: rezaei
f: mohammad l:
f:  l: kazemi
```

Answer (score 4):

I like sehe's answer, but it does not use deferred execution (the input sequences are eagerly enumerated by the calls to ToLookup). So after looking at the .NET sources for [LINQ-to-objects](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,577032c8811e20d3), I came up with this:

```
public static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> FullOuterJoin<TLeft, TRight, TKey, TResult>(
        this IEnumerable<TLeft> left,
        IEnumerable<TRight> right,
        Func<TLeft, TKey> leftKeySelector,
        Func<TRight, TKey> rightKeySelector,
        Func<TLeft, TRight, TKey, TResult> resultSelector,
        IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparator = null,
        TLeft defaultLeft = default(TLeft),
        TRight defaultRight = default(TRight))
    {
        if (left == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("left");
        if (right == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("right");
        if (leftKeySelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("leftKeySelector");
        if (rightKeySelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("rightKeySelector");
        if (resultSelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("resultSelector");

        comparator = comparator ?? EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default;
        return FullOuterJoinIterator(left, right, leftKeySelector, rightKeySelector, resultSelector, comparator, defaultLeft, defaultRight);
    }

    internal static IEnumerable<TResult> FullOuterJoinIterator<TLeft, TRight, TKey, TResult>(
        this IEnumerable<TLeft> left,
        IEnumerable<TRight> right,
        Func<TLeft, TKey> leftKeySelector,
        Func<TRight, TKey> rightKeySelector,
        Func<TLeft, TRight, TKey, TResult> resultSelector,
        IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparator,
        TLeft defaultLeft,
        TRight defaultRight)
    {
        var leftLookup = left.ToLookup(leftKeySelector, comparator);
        var rightLookup = right.ToLookup(rightKeySelector, comparator);
        var keys = leftLookup.Select(g => g.Key).Union(rightLookup.Select(g => g.Key), comparator);

        foreach (var key in keys)
            foreach (var leftValue in leftLookup[key].DefaultIfEmpty(defaultLeft))
                foreach (var rightValue in rightLookup[key].DefaultIfEmpty(defaultRight))
                    yield return resultSelector(leftValue, rightValue, key);
    }
}
```

This implementation has the following important properties:

- Deferred execution, input sequences will not be enumerated before the output sequence is enumerated.
- Only enumerates the input sequences once each.
- Preserves order of input sequences, in the sense that it will yield tuples in the order of the left sequence and then the right (for the keys not present in left sequence).

These properties are important, because they are what someone new to FullOuterJoin but experienced with LINQ will expect.

Comment: It does not preserve order of input sequences: Lookup doesn't guarantee that, so these foreaches will enumerate in some order of left side, then some order of right side not present in the left side. But relational order of elements is not preserved.

Comment: @IvanDanilov You are correct that this isn't actually in the contract. The implementation of ToLookup, however, uses an internal Lookup class in Enumerable.cs that keeps groupings in an insertion-ordered linked list and  uses this list to iterate through them. So in the current .NET version, order is guaranteed, but since MS unfortunately hasn't documented this, they could change it in later versions.

Comment: I tried it on .NET 4.5.1 on Win 8.1, and it does not preserve order.

Comment: "..the input sequences are eagerly enumerated by the calls to ToLookup". But your implementation does exactly the same.. Yielding doesn't give much here because of expenses on finite-state machine.

Comment: "input sequences will not be enumerated before the output sequence is enumerated"??? It's clear that you understand the effects of `ToLookup`, so how you can make this claim is a mystery to me. You're calling `ToLookup` twice. Before anything is yielded.

Comment: The Lookup calls are done when the first element of the result is requested, and not when the iterator is created. That's what deferred execution means. You could defer the enumeration of one input set even further, by iterating the left Enumerable directly instead of converting it to a Lookup, resulting in the extra benefit that the order of the left set is preserved.

Comment: This worked for me and as stated supports deferred execution... so +1 Order preserving is not important to me - not sure on what the results of the technical debate above are, maybe someone who understands it better can edit out the original incorrect claim if appropriate?

Answer (score 3):

I decided to add this as a separate answer as I am not positive it is tested enough. This is a re-implementation of the `FullOuterJoin` method using essentially a simplified, customized version of `LINQKit` `Invoke`/`Expand` for `Expression` so that it should work the Entity Framework. There's not much explanation as it is pretty much the same as my previous answer.

```
public static class Ext {
    private static Expression<Func<TP, TC, TResult>> CastSMBody<TP, TC, TResult>(LambdaExpression ex, TP unusedP, TC unusedC, TResult unusedRes) => (Expression<Func<TP, TC, TResult>>)ex;

    public static IQueryable<TResult> LeftOuterJoin<TLeft, TRight, TKey, TResult>(
        this IQueryable<TLeft> leftItems,
        IQueryable<TRight> rightItems,
        Expression<Func<TLeft, TKey>> leftKeySelector,
        Expression<Func<TRight, TKey>> rightKeySelector,
        Expression<Func<TLeft, TRight, TResult>> resultSelector) {

        // (lrg,r) => resultSelector(lrg.left, r)
        var sampleAnonLR = new { left = default(TLeft), rightg = default(IEnumerable<TRight>) };
        var parmP = Expression.Parameter(sampleAnonLR.GetType(), "lrg");
        var parmC = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TRight), "r");
        var argLeft = Expression.PropertyOrField(parmP, "left");
        var newleftrs = CastSMBody(Expression.Lambda(resultSelector.Apply(argLeft, parmC), parmP, parmC), sampleAnonLR, default(TRight), default(TResult));

        return leftItems.GroupJoin(rightItems, leftKeySelector, rightKeySelector, (left, rightg) => new { left, rightg }).SelectMany(r => r.rightg.DefaultIfEmpty(), newleftrs);
    }

    public static IQueryable<TResult> RightOuterJoin<TLeft, TRight, TKey, TResult>(
        this IQueryable<TLeft> leftItems,
        IQueryable<TRight> rightItems,
        Expression<Func<TLeft, TKey>> leftKeySelector,
        Expression<Func<TRight, TKey>> rightKeySelector,
        Expression<Func<TLeft, TRight, TResult>> resultSelector) {

        // (lgr,l) => resultSelector(l, lgr.right)
        var sampleAnonLR = new { leftg = default(IEnumerable<TLeft>), right = default(TRight) };
        var parmP = Expression.Parameter(sampleAnonLR.GetType(), "lgr");
        var parmC = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TLeft), "l");
        var argRight = Expression.PropertyOrField(parmP, "right");
        var newrightrs = CastSMBody(Expression.Lambda(resultSelector.Apply(parmC, argRight), parmP, parmC), sampleAnonLR, default(TLeft), default(TResult));

        return rightItems.GroupJoin(leftItems, rightKeySelector, leftKeySelector, (right, leftg) => new { leftg, right })
                         .SelectMany(l => l.leftg.DefaultIfEmpty(), newrightrs);
    }

    private static Expression<Func<TParm, TResult>> CastSBody<TParm, TResult>(LambdaExpression ex, TParm unusedP, TResult unusedRes) => (Expression<Func<TParm, TResult>>)ex;

    public static IQueryable<TResult> RightAntiSemiJoin<TLeft, TRight, TKey, TResult>(
        this IQueryable<TLeft> leftItems,
        IQueryable<TRight> rightItems,
        Expression<Func<TLeft, TKey>> leftKeySelector,
        Expression<Func<TRight, TKey>> rightKeySelector,
        Expression<Func<TLeft, TRight, TResult>> resultSelector) where TLeft : class where TRight : class where TResult : class {

        // newrightrs = lgr => resultSelector(default(TLeft), lgr.right)
        var sampleAnonLgR = new { leftg = (IEnumerable<TLeft>)null, right = default(TRight) };
        var parmLgR = Expression.Parameter(sampleAnonLgR.GetType(), "lgr");
        var argLeft = Expression.Constant(default(TLeft), typeof(TLeft));
        var argRight = Expression.PropertyOrField(parmLgR, "right");
        var newrightrs = CastSBody(Expression.Lambda(resultSelector.Apply(argLeft, argRight), parmLgR), sampleAnonLgR, default(TResult));

        return rightItems.GroupJoin(leftItems, rightKeySelector, leftKeySelector, (right, leftg) => new { leftg, right }).Where(lgr => !lgr.leftg.Any()).Select(newrightrs);
    }

    public static IQueryable<TResult> FullOuterJoin<TLeft, TRight, TKey, TResult>(
        this IQueryable<TLeft> leftItems,
        IQueryable<TRight> rightItems,
        Expression<Func<TLeft, TKey>> leftKeySelector,
        Expression<Func<TRight, TKey>> rightKeySelector,
        Expression<Func<TLeft, TRight, TResult>> resultSelector)  where TLeft : class where TRight : class where TResult : class {

        return leftItems.LeftOuterJoin(rightItems, leftKeySelector, rightKeySelector, resultSelector).Concat(leftItems.RightAntiSemiJoin(rightItems, leftKeySelector, rightKeySelector, resultSelector));
    }

    public static Expression Apply(this LambdaExpression e, params Expression[] args) {
        var b = e.Body;

        foreach (var pa in e.Parameters.Cast<ParameterExpression>().Zip(args, (p, a) => (p, a))) {
            b = b.Replace(pa.p, pa.a);
        }

        return b.PropagateNull();
    }

    public static Expression Replace(this Expression orig, Expression from, Expression to) => new ReplaceVisitor(from, to).Visit(orig);
    public class ReplaceVisitor : System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor {
        public readonly Expression from;
        public readonly Expression to;

        public ReplaceVisitor(Expression _from, Expression _to) {
            from = _from;
            to = _to;
        }

        public override Expression Visit(Expression node) => node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
    }

    public static Expression PropagateNull(this Expression orig) => new NullVisitor().Visit(orig);
    public class NullVisitor : System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor {
        public override Expression Visit(Expression node) {
            if (node is MemberExpression nme && nme.Expression is ConstantExpression nce && nce.Value == null)
                return Expression.Constant(null, nce.Type.GetMember(nme.Member.Name).Single().GetMemberType());
            else
                return base.Visit(node);
        }
    }

    public static Type GetMemberType(this MemberInfo member) {
        switch (member) {
            case FieldInfo mfi:
                return mfi.FieldType;
            case PropertyInfo mpi:
                return mpi.PropertyType;
            case EventInfo mei:
                return mei.EventHandlerType;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("MemberInfo must be if type FieldInfo, PropertyInfo or EventInfo", nameof(member));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: NetMage, impressive coding!

When I run it with a simple example, and when the [NullVisitor.Visit(..) gets invoked in [base.Visit(Node)], it throws a [System.ArgumentException: Argument Types do not match]. Which is true, as I'm using a [Guid] TKey and at some point the null visitor expects a [Guid?] Type.

May be I'm missing something.

I have a short example coded for EF 6.4.4. Please let me know how can I share this code with you.

Thanks!

Comment: @Troncho I normally use LINQPad for testing, so EF 6 isn't easily done. `base.Visit(node)` shouldn't throw an exception as that just recurses down the tree. I can access pretty much any code sharing service, but not setup a test database. Running it against my LINQ to SQL test seems to work fine, though.

Comment: @Troncho Is it possible you are joining between a `Guid` key and a `Guid?` foreign key?

Comment: I'm using LinqPad for testing too. My query threw the ArgumentException so I decided to debug it on VS2019 on [.Net Framework 4.7.1] and the latest EF 6. There I got to trace the real problem.
In order to test your code, I'm generating 2 separate data sets originating from the same [Persons] table. I filter both sets so that some records are unique to each set and some exist on both sets. [PersonId] is a [Primary Key] Guid (c#) / Uniqueidentifier (SqlServer) and neither set generate any null [PersonId] value.

Shared code: https://github.com/Troncho/EF_FullOuterJoin

Comment: I go this error when I use it with select with another class


'Unable to create a null constant value of type 'TestProject.Contollers.TableViewModel'. Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in this context.'

Comment: here is the code:

                    var first = context.tt1.Select(e => new TableViewModel
                    {
                        ID = e.ID1,
                        Title = e.Title1,
                    });

                    var second = context.tt2.Select(e => new TableViewModel
                    {
                        ID = e.ID1,
                        Title = e.Title,
                    });


                    var list = first.FullOuterJoin(second, a => a.ID, b => b.ID, (a, b) => new { a, b }).ToList();
                }

Comment: @Hosam.Yousof What happens if you try to replace `FullOuterJoin` with `Join`?

Answer (score 1):

I've written this extensions class for an app perhaps 6 years ago, and have been using it ever since in many solutions without issues. Hope it helps.

edit: I noticed some might not know how to use an extension class.

To use this extension class, just reference its namespace in your class by adding the following line
using joinext;

^ this should allow you to to see the intellisense of extension functions on any IEnumerable object collection you happen to use.

Hope this helps. Let me know if it's still not clear, and I'll hopefully write a sample example on how to use it.

Now here is the class:

```
namespace joinext
{    
public static class JoinExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<TResult> FullOuterJoin<TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult>(
            this IEnumerable<TOuter> outer,
            IEnumerable<TInner> inner,
            Func<TOuter, TKey> outerKeySelector,
            Func<TInner, TKey> innerKeySelector,
            Func<TOuter, TInner, TResult> resultSelector)
            where TInner : class
            where TOuter : class
        {
            var innerLookup = inner.ToLookup(innerKeySelector);
            var outerLookup = outer.ToLookup(outerKeySelector);

            var innerJoinItems = inner
                .Where(innerItem => !outerLookup.Contains(innerKeySelector(innerItem)))
                .Select(innerItem => resultSelector(null, innerItem));

            return outer
                .SelectMany(outerItem =>
                {
                    var innerItems = innerLookup[outerKeySelector(outerItem)];

                    return innerItems.Any() ? innerItems : new TInner[] { null };
                }, resultSelector)
                .Concat(innerJoinItems);
        }


        public static IEnumerable<TResult> LeftJoin<TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult>(
            this IEnumerable<TOuter> outer,
            IEnumerable<TInner> inner,
            Func<TOuter, TKey> outerKeySelector,
            Func<TInner, TKey> innerKeySelector,
            Func<TOuter, TInner, TResult> resultSelector)
        {
            return outer.GroupJoin(
                inner,
                outerKeySelector,
                innerKeySelector,
                (o, i) =>
                    new { o = o, i = i.DefaultIfEmpty() })
                    .SelectMany(m => m.i.Select(inn =>
                        resultSelector(m.o, inn)
                        ));

        }



        public static IEnumerable<TResult> RightJoin<TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult>(
            this IEnumerable<TOuter> outer,
            IEnumerable<TInner> inner,
            Func<TOuter, TKey> outerKeySelector,
            Func<TInner, TKey> innerKeySelector,
            Func<TOuter, TInner, TResult> resultSelector)
        {
            return inner.GroupJoin(
                outer,
                innerKeySelector,
                outerKeySelector,
                (i, o) =>
                    new { i = i, o = o.DefaultIfEmpty() })
                    .SelectMany(m => m.o.Select(outt =>
                        resultSelector(outt, m.i)
                        ));

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems the function in `SelectMany` cannot be converted to a LINQ2SQL-worthy expression tree, it seems.

Comment: edc65. I know it might be a silly question if you done that already. But just in case (as I've noticed some don't know), you just need to reference the namespace joinext.

Comment: O. R. Mapper, let me know with what type of collection you wanted it to work.
It should work fine with any IEnumerable collection

Answer (score 1):

Performs a in-memory streaming enumeration over both inputs and invokes the selector for each row. If there is no correlation at the current iteration, **one of the selector arguments will be null**.

Example:

```
   var result = left.FullOuterJoin(
         right, 
         x=>left.Key, 
         x=>right.Key, 
         (l,r) => new { LeftKey = l?.Key, RightKey=r?.Key });
```

- Requires an IComparer for the correlation type, uses the Comparer.Default if not provided.
- Requires that 'OrderBy' is applied to the input enumerables

  ```
  /// <summary>
  /// Performs a full outer join on two <see cref="IEnumerable{T}" />.
  /// </summary>
  /// <typeparam name="TLeft"></typeparam>
  /// <typeparam name="TValue"></typeparam>
  /// <typeparam name="TRight"></typeparam>
  /// <typeparam name="TResult"></typeparam>
  /// <param name="left"></param>
  /// <param name="right"></param>
  /// <param name="leftKeySelector"></param>
  /// <param name="rightKeySelector"></param>
  /// <param name="selector">Expression defining result type</param>
  /// <param name="keyComparer">A comparer if there is no default for the type</param>
  /// <returns></returns>
  [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough]
  public static IEnumerable<TResult> FullOuterJoin<TLeft, TRight, TValue, TResult>(
      this IEnumerable<TLeft> left,
      IEnumerable<TRight> right,
      Func<TLeft, TValue> leftKeySelector,
      Func<TRight, TValue> rightKeySelector,
      Func<TLeft, TRight, TResult> selector,
      IComparer<TValue> keyComparer = null)
      where TLeft: class
      where TRight: class
      where TValue : IComparable
  {

      keyComparer = keyComparer ?? Comparer<TValue>.Default;

      using (var enumLeft = left.OrderBy(leftKeySelector).GetEnumerator())
      using (var enumRight = right.OrderBy(rightKeySelector).GetEnumerator())
      {

          var hasLeft = enumLeft.MoveNext();
          var hasRight = enumRight.MoveNext();
          while (hasLeft || hasRight)
          {

              var currentLeft = enumLeft.Current;
              var valueLeft = hasLeft ? leftKeySelector(currentLeft) : default(TValue);

              var currentRight = enumRight.Current;
              var valueRight = hasRight ? rightKeySelector(currentRight) : default(TValue);

              int compare =
                  !hasLeft ? 1
                  : !hasRight ? -1
                  : keyComparer.Compare(valueLeft, valueRight);

              switch (compare)
              {
                  case 0:
                      // The selector matches. An inner join is achieved
                      yield return selector(currentLeft, currentRight);
                      hasLeft = enumLeft.MoveNext();
                      hasRight = enumRight.MoveNext();
                      break;
                  case -1:
                      yield return selector(currentLeft, default(TRight));
                      hasLeft = enumLeft.MoveNext();
                      break;
                  case 1:
                      yield return selector(default(TLeft), currentRight);
                      hasRight = enumRight.MoveNext();
                      break;
              }
          }

      }

  }
  ```

Comment: That's a heroic effort to make things "streaming". Sadly, all the gain is lost at the first step, where you perform `OrderBy` on both key projections. [`OrderBy` buffers the entire sequence, for the obvious reasons](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/marcelolr/2010/05/06/some-performance-notes-on-enumerable-linq-operators/).

Comment: @sehe You are definitely correct for Linq to Objects. If the IEnumerable<T> are IQueryable<T> the source should sort - no time to test though. If I am wrong about this, simply replacing the input IEnumerable<T> with IQueryable<T> should sort in the source/database.

Answer (score 0):

Full outer join for two or more tables:
First extract the column that you want to join on.

```
var DatesA = from A in db.T1 select A.Date; 
var DatesB = from B in db.T2 select B.Date; 
var DatesC = from C in db.T3 select C.Date;            

var Dates = DatesA.Union(DatesB).Union(DatesC);
```

Then use left outer join between the extracted column and main tables.

```
var Full_Outer_Join =

(from A in Dates
join B in db.T1
on A equals B.Date into AB 

from ab in AB.DefaultIfEmpty()
join C in db.T2
on A equals C.Date into ABC 

from abc in ABC.DefaultIfEmpty()
join D in db.T3
on A equals D.Date into ABCD

from abcd in ABCD.DefaultIfEmpty() 
select new { A, ab, abc, abcd })
.AsEnumerable();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that LINQ join clause isn't the correct solution to this problem, because of join clause purpose isn't to accumulate data in such way as required for this task solution. The code to merge created separate collections becomes too complicated, maybe it is OK for learning purposes, but not for real applications. One of the ways how to solve this problem is in the code below:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<FirstName> firstNames = new List<FirstName>();
        firstNames.Add(new FirstName { ID = 1, Name = "John" });
        firstNames.Add(new FirstName { ID = 2, Name = "Sue" });

        List<LastName> lastNames = new List<LastName>();
        lastNames.Add(new LastName { ID = 1, Name = "Doe" });
        lastNames.Add(new LastName { ID = 3, Name = "Smith" });

        HashSet<int> ids = new HashSet<int>();
        foreach (var name in firstNames)
        {
            ids.Add(name.ID);
        }
        foreach (var name in lastNames)
        {
            ids.Add(name.ID);
        }
        List<FullName> fullNames = new List<FullName>();
        foreach (int id in ids)
        {
            FullName fullName = new FullName();
            fullName.ID = id;
            FirstName firstName = firstNames.Find(f => f.ID == id);
            fullName.FirstName = firstName != null ? firstName.Name : string.Empty;
            LastName lastName = lastNames.Find(l => l.ID == id);
            fullName.LastName = lastName != null ? lastName.Name : string.Empty;
            fullNames.Add(fullName);
        }
    }
}
public class FirstName
{
    public int ID;

    public string Name;
}

public class LastName
{
    public int ID;

    public string Name;
}
class FullName
{
    public int ID;

    public string FirstName;

    public string LastName;
}
```

If real collections are large for HashSet formation instead foreach loops can be used the code below:

```
List<int> firstIds = firstNames.Select(f => f.ID).ToList();
List<int> LastIds = lastNames.Select(l => l.ID).ToList();
HashSet<int> ids = new HashSet<int>(firstIds.Union(LastIds));//Only unique IDs will be included in HashSet
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank You everybody for the interesting posts!

I modified the code because in my case I needed

- a **personalized join predicate**
- a **personalized union distinct comparer**

For the ones interested this is my modified code (in VB, sorry)

```
    Module MyExtensions
        <Extension()>
        Friend Function FullOuterJoin(Of TA, TB, TResult)(ByVal a As IEnumerable(Of TA), ByVal b As IEnumerable(Of TB), ByVal joinPredicate As Func(Of TA, TB, Boolean), ByVal projection As Func(Of TA, TB, TResult), ByVal comparer As IEqualityComparer(Of TResult)) As IEnumerable(Of TResult)
            Dim joinL =
                From xa In a
                From xb In b.Where(Function(x) joinPredicate(xa, x)).DefaultIfEmpty()
                Select projection(xa, xb)
            Dim joinR =
                From xb In b
                From xa In a.Where(Function(x) joinPredicate(x, xb)).DefaultIfEmpty()
                Select projection(xa, xb)
            Return joinL.Union(joinR, comparer)
        End Function
    End Module

    Dim fullOuterJoin = lefts.FullOuterJoin(
        rights,
        Function(left, right) left.Code = right.Code And (left.Amount [...] Or left.Description.Contains [...]),
        Function(left, right) New CompareResult(left, right),
        New MyEqualityComparer
    )

    Public Class MyEqualityComparer
        Implements IEqualityComparer(Of CompareResult)

        Private Function GetMsg(obj As CompareResult) As String
            Dim msg As String = ""
            msg &= obj.Code & "_"
            [...]
            Return msg
        End Function

        Public Overloads Function Equals(x As CompareResult, y As CompareResult) As Boolean Implements IEqualityComparer(Of CompareResult).Equals
            Return Me.GetMsg(x) = Me.GetMsg(y)
        End Function

        Public Overloads Function GetHashCode(obj As CompareResult) As Integer Implements IEqualityComparer(Of CompareResult).GetHashCode
            Return Me.GetMsg(obj).GetHashCode
        End Function
    End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yet another full outer join**

As was not that happy with the simplicity and the readability of the other propositions, I ended up with this :

It does not have the pretension to be fast ( about 800 ms to join 1000 * 1000 on a 2020m CPU : 2.4ghz / 2cores). To me, it is just a compact and casual full outer join.

It works the same as a SQL FULL OUTER JOIN (duplicates conservation)

Cheers ;-)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
namespace NS
{
public static class DataReunion
{
    public static List<Tuple<T1, T2>> FullJoin<T1, T2, TKey>(List<T1> List1, Func<T1, TKey> KeyFunc1, List<T2> List2, Func<T2, TKey> KeyFunc2)
    {
        List<Tuple<T1, T2>> result = new List<Tuple<T1, T2>>();

        Tuple<TKey, T1>[] identifiedList1 = List1.Select(_ => Tuple.Create(KeyFunc1(_), _)).OrderBy(_ => _.Item1).ToArray();
        Tuple<TKey, T2>[] identifiedList2 = List2.Select(_ => Tuple.Create(KeyFunc2(_), _)).OrderBy(_ => _.Item1).ToArray();

        identifiedList1.Where(_ => !identifiedList2.Select(__ => __.Item1).Contains(_.Item1)).ToList().ForEach(_ => {
            result.Add(Tuple.Create<T1, T2>(_.Item2, default(T2)));
        });

        result.AddRange(
            identifiedList1.Join(identifiedList2, left => left.Item1, right => right.Item1, (left, right) => Tuple.Create<T1, T2>(left.Item2, right.Item2)).ToList()
        );

        identifiedList2.Where(_ => !identifiedList1.Select(__ => __.Item1).Contains(_.Item1)).ToList().ForEach(_ => {
            result.Add(Tuple.Create<T1, T2>(default(T1), _.Item2));
        });

        return result;
    }
}
}
```

The idea is to

1. Build Ids based on provided key function builders
2. Process left only items
3. Process inner join
4. Process right only items

Here is a succinct test that goes with it :

Place a break point at the end to manually verify that it behaves as expected

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using NS;

namespace Tests
{
[TestClass]
public class DataReunionTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test()
    {
        List<Tuple<Int32, Int32, String>> A = new List<Tuple<Int32, Int32, String>>();
        List<Tuple<Int32, Int32, String>> B = new List<Tuple<Int32, Int32, String>>();

        Random rnd = new Random();

        /* Comment the testing block you do not want to run
        /* Solution to test a wide range of keys*/

        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i += 1)
        {
            A.Add(Tuple.Create(rnd.Next(1, 101), rnd.Next(1, 101), "A"));
            B.Add(Tuple.Create(rnd.Next(1, 101), rnd.Next(1, 101), "B"));
        }

        /* Solution for essential testing*/

        A.Add(Tuple.Create(1, 2, "B11"));
        A.Add(Tuple.Create(1, 2, "B12"));
        A.Add(Tuple.Create(1, 3, "C11"));
        A.Add(Tuple.Create(1, 3, "C12"));
        A.Add(Tuple.Create(1, 3, "C13"));
        A.Add(Tuple.Create(1, 4, "D1"));

        B.Add(Tuple.Create(1, 1, "A21"));
        B.Add(Tuple.Create(1, 1, "A22"));
        B.Add(Tuple.Create(1, 1, "A23"));
        B.Add(Tuple.Create(1, 2, "B21"));
        B.Add(Tuple.Create(1, 2, "B22"));
        B.Add(Tuple.Create(1, 2, "B23"));
        B.Add(Tuple.Create(1, 3, "C2"));
        B.Add(Tuple.Create(1, 5, "E2"));

        Func<Tuple<Int32, Int32, String>, Tuple<Int32, Int32>> key = (_) => Tuple.Create(_.Item1, _.Item2);

        var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var res = DataReunion.FullJoin(A, key, B, key);
        watch.Stop();
        var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        String aser = JToken.FromObject(res).ToString(Formatting.Indented);
        Console.Write(elapsedMs);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

For Linq for Objects it can be done something like this:

```
static void TestFullJoin()
{
    var clientChanges = new List<PropertyChange> 
    {
        new PropertyChange(1, "111"),
        new PropertyChange(2, "222"),
        new PropertyChange(3, "333")
    };
    var serverProperties = new List<PropertyView>
    {
        new PropertyView(2, "222"),
        new PropertyView(3, "333"),
        new PropertyView(4, "444")
    };

    var fullOuterJoin = clientChanges
    .GroupJoin(serverProperties, c => c.Id, s => s.Id, (c, s) => new JoinResult(c, s.FirstOrDefault()))
    .Union(serverProperties
        .GroupJoin(clientChanges, s => s.Id, r => r.Id, (s, c) => new JoinResult(c.FirstOrDefault(), s)));

    foreach (var (clientProperty, serverProperty) in fullOuterJoin)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Left: {clientProperty}, Right: {serverProperty}");
    }
}

public record JoinResult(PropertyChange? ClientProperty, PropertyView? ServerProperty);
public record PropertyChange(int Id, string Name);
public record PropertyView(int Id, string Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have, create two maps and iterate over the union of keys

```cs
public static IEnumerable<TResult> FullOuterJoin<TOuter,TInner,TKey,TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TOuter> outer,
    IEnumerable<TInner> inner,
    Func<TOuter, TKey> outerKeySelector,
    Func<TInner, TKey> innerKeySelector,
    Func<TOuter?,TInner?,TResult> resultSelector) where TKey: notnull
{
    var innerMap = inner.ToDictionary(innerKeySelector);
    var outerMap = outer.ToDictionary(outerKeySelector);

    var keys = innerMap.Keys.Union(outerMap.Keys);

    foreach(var key in keys)
    {
        var hasInner = innerMap.TryGetValue(key, out var innerValue);
        var hasOuter = outerMap.TryGetValue(key, out var outerValue);

        if (hasInner && hasOuter)
        {
            yield return resultSelector(outerValue, innerValue);
        }
        else if (hasInner)
        {
            yield return resultSelector(default, innerValue);
        }
        else if (hasOuter)
        {
            yield return resultSelector(outerValue, default);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I really hate these linq expressions, this is why SQL exists:

```
select isnull(fn.id, ln.id) as id, fn.firstname, ln.lastname
   from firstnames fn
   full join lastnames ln on ln.id=fn.id
```

Create this as sql view in database and import it as entity.

Of course, (distinct) union of left and right joins will make it too, but it is stupid.

Comment: Why not just drop as many abstractions as possible and do this in machine code? (Hint: because the higher order abstractions make life easier for the programmer). This doesn't answer the question and looks to me more like a rant against LINQ.

Comment: Who said the data comes from a database?

Comment: Of course, it is database, there are words "outer join" in question :) https://www.google.cz/search?q=outer+join

Comment: I understand that this is "old fashion" solution, but before downvoting, compare its complexity with other solutions :) Except the accepted one, it is of course the correct one.

Comment: Of course it can be a database or not. I am searching for a solution with an outer join between lists in memory