# How to I get this LINQ full-outer-join to function properly?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, full-outer-join

I am building a WPF application that monitors a directory on the users computer. The app uploads files from the monitored directory and then saves off some information into a SQLite db. Part of the business processing is to not re-process files that have already been uploaded and to re-upload files that have been uploaded but have changed since the last upload.

I have two helper methods that build and return a `List<FileMetaData>` that I used [LINQ - Full Outer Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489987/linq-full-outer-join) to join the. My problem is that the code doesn't seem to work when I use my `FileMetaData` object. It seems like everything should all work but I'm at a loss as to why it's not working. I would normally try to post as a comment on the other thread but I don't currently have the "Rep" here to do that.

Below is a sample I've built that shows my problem if you run it in [LINQpad](http://www.linqpad.net/). Make sure you set the language as "C# Program" before you click the run button. What should I do differently to have the sample work with the objects? Thanks a ton!

```
    void Main()
    {
        var dbItems = new List<FileMetaData>() { 
                new FileMetaData {FilePath = "C:\\Foo.txt", DbTimestamp = "1" },
                new FileMetaData {FilePath = "C:\\FooBar.txt", DbTimestamp = "3" },
            };

        var fsItems = new List<FileMetaData>() {
                new FileMetaData {FilePath = "C:\\Bar.txt", FsTimestamp = "2" },
                new FileMetaData {FilePath = "C:\\FooBar.txt", FsTimestamp = "3" },
            };

            var leftOuter = from d in dbItems
                    join f in fsItems on d.FilePath equals f.FilePath
                    into temp
                    from o in temp.DefaultIfEmpty(new FileMetaData(){})
                    select new FileMetaData { 
                        FilePath = d.FilePath, 
                        DbTimestamp = d.DbTimestamp,
                        FsTimestamp = o.FsTimestamp,
                    };

            var rightOuter = from f in fsItems
                    join d in dbItems on f.FilePath equals d.FilePath
                    into temp
                    from o in temp.DefaultIfEmpty(new FileMetaData(){})
                    select new FileMetaData { 
                        FilePath = f.FilePath, 
                        DbTimestamp = o.DbTimestamp,
                        FsTimestamp = f.FsTimestamp,
                    };

            var full = leftOuter.AsEnumerable().Union(rightOuter.AsEnumerable());

            leftOuter.Dump("Left Results");
            rightOuter.Dump("Right Results");

            full.Dump("Full Results");
    }

    // Define other methods and classes here
    public class FileMetaData
    {
        public string FilePath;
        public string DbTimestamp;
        public string FsTimestamp;
    }
```

EDIT:

The answer below was exactly what I was looking for. I implemented the `IEqualityComparer` as defined below and changed my call to `var full = leftOuter.Union(rightOuter, new FileMetaDataCompare())`...

```
    public class FileMetaDataCompare : IEqualityComparer<FileMetaData>
    {
        public bool Equals(FileMetaData x, FileMetaData y)
        {
            var areEqual = x.FilePath == y.FilePath;
            areEqual = areEqual && x.DbTimestamp == y.DbTimestamp;
            areEqual = areEqual && x.FsTimestamp == y.FsTimestamp;

            return areEqual;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(FileMetaData obj)
        {
            var hCode = string.Concat(obj.FilePath, obj.DbTimestamp, obj.FsTimestamp);
            return hCode.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `Union` will give you the results *eliminating duplicates* by checking for equality.  When you use anonymous types, the definition of equality is 'all fields have an equal value'.  when you declare a type, it will use the `Equals` method.  Since you have not overridden `Equals`, it defaults to `ReferenceEquals`, which means that two separate instances are not equal regardless of their field values.

Three ways to solve this:

1) Use anonymous types in your queries and convert to defined types after Union:

```
var full = leftOuter.Union(rightOuter).Select(
    i=> new FileMetaData {
        FilePath = i.FilePath,
        DbTimestamp = i.DbTimestamp,
        FsTimestamp = i.FsTimestamp
    });
```

2) Define an `IEqualityComparer<FileMetaData>` class that defines equality thay you want to (just FilePath?  all fields?) and pass an instance of it to `Union()`

3) Override `Equals()` (and `GetHashCode()`) in `FileMetaData`.

2) and 3) will be very similar, but overriding `Equals()` can (and will) be used whenever you check for equality, not just in this situation.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the answer. I completely blanked on IEqualityComparer.