# Linq distinct query on specific column

Tags: c#, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LINQ select distinct c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673584/linq-select-distinct-c-sharp)

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
List<string> manufacturerFilters = new List<string>(){"Honda", "Ford", "Jaguar", "BMW"};
var products = (from p in context.Products
                where p.DeletedSince.Equals(null)
                && manufacturerFilters.Contains(p.Manufacturer.Name)
                && p.SomeValue == 123).Distinct(**p.Manufacturer**).Take(4);
```

Now this gives me a list of products that belong to the 4 manufacturers in my filter list. 
But what i really want, is 4 products, 1 from each manufacturer. That is why i put this Distinct in my query, which of course, is not working..

How should i do this type of distinct query?

Comment: You may want to try `DistinctBy` of [morelinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/)

Answer (score 0):

```
.Distinct(**p.Manufacturer.Name**)
```

p.Manufacturer is of reference type and hence it take all as distinct because they have different refernces.I hope this will help. If you want .Distinct(**p.Manufacturer**) to work then you will have to specify Comparer.