# Normalize objects using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have an `IEnumerable<RuleSelection>` with these properties:

```
public class RuleSelection{
  public int RuleId { get; set;}
  public int? CriteriaId { get; set; }
  public int? CriteriaSourceId{ get; set; }
}
```

`RuleId` in `RuleSelection` is not unique.

Can I write a linq query to normalize these into `IEnumerable<Rule>` which would be:

```
public class Rule{
  public int RuleId { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<int> Criteria { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<int> CriteriaSource { get; set; }
}
```

`Rule.RuleId` would be unique and the properties `Criteria` and `CriteriaSource` would include all the `CriteriaId`'s and `CriteriaSourceId`'s for the `RuleId` respectively.

Comment: If each Criteria belongs to one CriteriaSource, then shouldn't they be one entity like a Class with properties of Criteria and CriteriaSource? And if the Criteria is one thing, it should be Criterion.

Comment: +1 ... because Criterion

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like:

```
var rules = selections.GroupBy(rs => rs.RuleId)
                      .Select(g => new Rule {
                                  RuleId = g.Key,
                                  Criteria = g.Select(rs => rs.CriteriaId)
                                              .Where(c => c != null)
                                              .Select(c => c.Value)
                                              .ToList(),
                                  CriteriaSource = g.Select(rs => rs.CriteriaSourceId)
                                                    .Where(c => c != null)
                                                    .Select(c => c.Value)
                                                    .ToList(),
                              });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using my FullOuterGroupJoin extension method

- [LINQ - Full Outer Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489987/linq-full-outer-join/13503860#13503860)

you could:

```
theRules.FullOuterGroupJoin(theRules,
        r => r.RuleId,
        r => r.RuleId,
        (crit, critSource, id) => new Rule { 
            RuleId = id, 
            Criteria = crit
                .Where(r => r.CriteriaId.HasValue)
                .Select(r => r.CriteriaId.Value),
            CriteriaSource = critSource
                .Where(r => r.CriteriaSourceId.HasValue)
                .Select(r => r.CriteriaSourceId.Value),
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

To write this:

```
var rules =
    from sel in selections
    group sel by sel.RuleId into rg
    select new Rule {
        RuleId = rg.Key,
        Criteria = rg.Select(r => r.CriteriaId).FilterValues(),
        CriteriaSource = rg.Select(r => r.CriteriaSourceId).FilterValues(),
    };
```

I created the following `FilterValues` extension (to eliminate duplication):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FilterValues<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T?> items)
    where T : struct
{
    // omitting argument validation
    return 
        from item in items 
        where item.HasValue
        select item.Value;
}
```

I set out to provide essentially a pure query-syntax version of JonSkeet's answer. I gave up on that in effort to remove duplication for the property assignments and wound up with this combination extension & query-syntax approach.