# Linq-to-Entities Join vs GroupJoin

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

Can someone please explain what a `GroupJoin()` is?

How is it different from a regular `Join()`?

Is it commonly used?

Is it only for method syntax? What about query syntax? (A c# code example would be nice)

Comment: According to MSDN, a group join is a join clause with an into expression.  [join clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx) has more information and code samples.  It's essentially an inner join (if no elements in the right match any in the left, you get a null result); however the result is organized into groups.

Comment: var lookup = inner.ToLookup(innerKeySelector, comparer); 
foreach (var outerElement in outer) 
{ 
    var key = outerKeySelector(outerElement); 
    foreach (var innerElement in lookup[key]) 
    { 
        yield return resultSelector(outerElement, innerElement); 
    } 
}

Answer (score 494, accepted):

### Behaviour

Suppose you have two lists:

```
Id  Value
1   A
2   B
3   C

Id  ChildValue
1   a1
1   a2
1   a3
2   b1
2   b2
```

When you **`Join`** the two lists on the `Id` field the result will be:

```
Value ChildValue
A     a1
A     a2
A     a3
B     b1
B     b2
```

When you **`GroupJoin`** the two lists on the `Id` field the result will be:

```
Value  ChildValues
A      [a1, a2, a3]
B      [b1, b2]
C      []
```

So `Join` produces a flat (tabular) result of parent and child values.
`GroupJoin` produces a list of entries in the first list, each with a group of joined entries in the second list.

That's why `Join` is the equivalent of `INNER JOIN` in SQL: there are no entries for `C`. While `GroupJoin` is the equivalent of `OUTER JOIN`: `C` is in the result set, but with an empty list of related entries (in an SQL result set there would be a row `C - null`).

### Syntax

So let the two lists be `IEnumerable<Parent>` and `IEnumerable<Child>` respectively. (In case of Linq to Entities: `IQueryable<T>`).

**`Join`** syntax would be

```cs
from p in Parent
join c in Child on p.Id equals c.Id
select new { p.Value, c.ChildValue }
```

returning an `IEnumerable<X>` where X is an anonymous type with two properties, `Value` and `ChildValue`. This query syntax uses the [`Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675.aspx) method under the hood.

**`GroupJoin`** syntax would be

```cs
from p in Parent
join c in Child on p.Id equals c.Id into g
select new { Parent = p, Children = g }
```

returning an `IEnumerable<Y>` where Y is an anonymous type consisting of one property of type `Parent` and a property of type `IEnumerable<Child>`. This query syntax uses the [`GroupJoin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534297.aspx) method under the hood.

We could just do `select g` in the latter query, which would select an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Child>>`, say a list of lists. In many cases the select with the parent included is more useful.

### Some use cases

#### 1. Producing a flat outer join.

As said, the statement ...

```cs
from p in Parent
join c in Child on p.Id equals c.Id into g
select new { Parent = p, Children = g }
```

... produces a list of parents with child groups. This can be turned into a flat list of parent-child pairs by two small additions:

```cs
from p in parents
join c in children on p.Id equals c.Id into g // <= into
from c in g.DefaultIfEmpty()               // <= flattens the groups
select new { Parent = p.Value, Child = c?.ChildValue }
```

The result is similar to

```cs
Value Child
A     a1
A     a2
A     a3
B     b1
B     b2
C     (null)
```

Note that the *range variable* `c` is reused in the above statement. Doing this, any `join` statement can simply be converted to an `outer join` by adding the equivalent of `into g from c in g.DefaultIfEmpty()` to an existing `join` statement.

This is where query (or comprehensive) syntax shines. Method (or fluent) syntax shows what really happens, but it's hard to write:

```cs
parents.GroupJoin(children, p => p.Id, c => c.Id, (p, c) => new { p, c })
       .SelectMany(x => x.c.DefaultIfEmpty(), (x,c) => new { x.p.Value, c?.ChildValue } )
```

So a flat `outer join` in LINQ is a `GroupJoin`, flattened by `SelectMany`.

#### 2. Preserving order

Suppose the list of parents is a bit longer. Some UI produces a list of selected parents as `Id` values in a fixed order. Let's use:

```cs
var ids = new[] { 3,7,2,4 };
```

Now the selected parents must be filtered from the parents list in this exact order.

If we do ...

```cs
var result = parents.Where(p => ids.Contains(p.Id));
```

... the order of `parents` will determine the result. If the parents are ordered by `Id`, the result will be parents 2, 3, 4, 7. Not good. However, we can also use `join` to filter the list. And by using `ids` as first list, the order will be preserved:

```cs
from id in ids
join p in parents on id equals p.Id
select p
```

The result is parents 3, 7, 2, 4.

Comment: So in a GroupJoin, the child values will contain objects, that contain the related values?

Comment: As you said GroupJoin is like a outer join but that syntax (purely linq for group join) says it is not like outer join but left outer join.

Comment: I think I would specify that the "Flat Outer Join" is a Left Outer Join.

Answer (score 21):

According to [eduLINQ](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/category/edulinq/):

> The best way to get to grips with what GroupJoin does is to think of
>   Join. There, the overall idea was that we looked through the "outer"
>   input sequence, found all the matching items from the "inner" sequence
>   (based on a key projection on each sequence) and then yielded pairs of
>   matching elements. **GroupJoin is similar, except that instead of
>   yielding pairs of elements, it yields a single result for each "outer"
>   item based on that item and the sequence of matching "inner" items**.

The only difference is in return statement:

**Join**:

```
var lookup = inner.ToLookup(innerKeySelector, comparer); 
foreach (var outerElement in outer) 
{ 
    var key = outerKeySelector(outerElement); 
    foreach (var innerElement in lookup[key]) 
    { 
        yield return resultSelector(outerElement, innerElement); 
    } 
}
```

**GroupJoin**:

```
var lookup = inner.ToLookup(innerKeySelector, comparer); 
foreach (var outerElement in outer) 
{ 
    var key = outerKeySelector(outerElement); 
    yield return resultSelector(outerElement, lookup[key]); 
}
```

Read more here:

- [Reimplementing LINQ to Objects: Part 19 - Join](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/12/31/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-19-join/)
- [Reimplementing LINQ to Objects: Part 22 - GroupJoin](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/01/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-22-groupjoin/)

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose you have two different classes:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name, Email;
    
    public Person(string name, string email)
    {
        Name = name;
        Email = email;
    }
}
```

```
class Data
{
    public string Mail, SlackId;
    
    public Data(string mail, string slackId)
    {
        Mail = mail;
        SlackId = slackId;
    }
}
```

Now, let's Prepare data to work with:

```
var people = new Person[]
    {
        new Person("Sudi", "sudi@try.cd"),
        new Person("Simba", "simba@try.cd"),
        new Person("Sarah", string.Empty)
    };
    
    var records = new Data[]
    {
        new Data("sudi@try.cd", "Sudi_Try"),
        new Data("sudi@try.cd", "Sudi@Test"),
        new Data("simba@try.cd", "SimbaLion")
    };
```

You will note that sudi@try.cd has got two slackIds. I have made that for demonstrating how
Join works.

Let's now construct the query to join Person with Data:

```
var query = people.Join(records,
        x => x.Email,
        y => y.Mail,
        (person, record) => new { Name = person.Name, SlackId = record.SlackId});
    Console.WriteLine(query);
```

After constructing the query, you could also iterate over it with a foreach like so:

```
foreach (var item in query)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{item.Name} has Slack ID {item.SlackId}");
    }
```

Let's also output the result for GroupJoin:

```
Console.WriteLine(
    
        people.GroupJoin(
            records,
            x => x.Email,
            y => y.Mail,
            (person, recs) => new {
                Name = person.Name,
                SlackIds = recs.Select(r => r.SlackId).ToArray() // You could materialize //whatever way you want.
            }
        ));
```

You will notice that the *GroupJoin* will put all SlackIds in a single group.