# What's the method based syntax equivalent of join into

Tags: linq

I [found](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/linq/UXPF181012-SQL-Joins-with-C) the following linq expression, and I wonder how does the `into` keyword translate to in method based syntax?

```
var q = from pd in dataContext.tblProducts 
        join od in dataContext.tblOrders on pd.ProductID equals od.ProductID 
        into t 
        from rt in t.DefaultIfEmpty() 
        orderby pd.ProductID 
        select pd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15599143/2998271) by [@GertArnold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/861716/gert-arnold), `group ... into` linq query syntax uses [GroupJoin()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534297.aspx) method under the hood :

```
var q1 = from pd in dataContext.tblProducts 
        join od in dataContext.tblOrders on pd.ProductID equals od.ProductID 
        into t
        select t;

var q2 = dataContext.tblProducts
                    .GroupJoin(dataContext.tblOrders
                                , pd => pd.ProductID
                                , od => od.ProductID
                                , (pd, ods) => select new 
                                                    {
                                                        Product = pd,
                                                        Orders = ods
                                                    });
```

Both expression in sample above do grouping operation in similar way, despite the return value are different.

Answer (score 2):

All these transformations are described in C# specification. **7.16.2 Query expression translation** is all about that part of C#.

According to that specification there are two cases for `join`  with an `into`:

> A query expression with a `join` clause with an `into` followed by a
>   `select` clause
>
> ```
> from x1 in e1
> join x2 in e2 on k1 equals k2 into g
> select v
> ```
>
> is translated into
>
> ```
> ( e1 ) . GroupJoin( e2 , x1 => k1 , x2 => k2 , ( x1 , g ) => v )
> ```
>
> A query expression with a `join` clause with an `into` followed by
>   something other than a `select` clause
>
> ```
> from x1 in e1
> join x2 in e2 on k1 equals k2 into g
> …
> ```
>
> is translated into
>
> ```
> from * in ( e1 ) . GroupJoin(
>   e2 , x1 => k1 , x2 => k2 , ( x1 , g ) => new { x1 , g })
> …
> ```