# How can I use LINQ to select columns from multiple tables with Count and Group By?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

How can I use LINQ to select columns from multiple tables with Count and Group By?

This is my SQL query in C# and I want to convert it to a LINQ query.

```
string sqlProduct = string.Format(@"SELECT protype.idType, TypeName, **COUNT(idPro) as proNumber** 
                                    FROM protype, product 
                                    WHERE protype.idType=product.idType 
                                    **GROUP BY protype.idType, TypeName** 
                                    ORDER BY TypeName");
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 dt = Shop_Query.Select_Query(sqlProduct);
 lvMenu.DataSource = dt;
 lvMenu.DataBind();
```

Comment: Is it ok to use a join?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var query = dbContext.Protypes.Join(dbContext.Products,
                  protype => protype.idType,
                  product => product.idType,
                  (protype, product) => new { Protype = protype, Product = product })
                  .GroupBy(s => new { s.Protype.idType, Product.TypeName })
                  .Select(s => new
                  {
                     IdType = s.First().Protype.idType,
                     TypeName = s.First().Product.TypeName,
                     Count = s.Count()
                  });
```

there are lots of assumption in this query.

- I've assumed your Linq-to-Sql context to be `dbContext`
- I've assumed your context classes to be named as `Products` and `ProTypes`
- I've assumed `TypeName` field belongs to Product table

Now you need to learn about linq [GroupBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595289/linq-to-entities-join-vs-groupjoin) and Linq [Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767709/c-sharp-joins-where-with-linq-and-lambda)