# Linq group outer joins projected on a viewmodel

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel, linq-group

I have been scouting the internet for the past 2 days to find a solution to grouping the below linq query on BookId  to no avail.  The query works but I want to reoganise it so that It can group on BookId or BookTitle.

**models**

```
Book(BookId, Title, Author, ISBN, Location,  BookTypeId, StockLogValue) 
Booktype(BookTypeId, BookTypeName)
Stock(StockId, bookId, quantity, date_added)
Transact (transactionId, TransactionTypeId, BookId, Quantity, TransactDate)
TransactionType( TransactionTypeId, TransactionTypeName)
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Report(int? year, int? month, int? BkId)
    {
        var query = ReportYrMn( year, month, BkId);
        return View(query);
    }
     public IEnumerable ReportYrMn(int? year, int? month, int? BkId)
    {
        var query =
            (from bk in db.Books
             join tr in db.Transacts.Where(a => a.TransactDate.Month == month && a.TransactDate.Year == year && a.TransactType.TransactTypeName == "sale") on bk.BookId equals tr.BookId into trs
             from x in trs.DefaultIfEmpty()
             join tr2 in db.Transacts.Where(a => a.TransactDate.Month == month && a.TransactDate.Year == year && a.TransactType.TransactTypeName == "gift") on bk.BookId equals tr2.BookId into trs2
             from x2 in trs2.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new ReportViewModel { BookTitle = bk.BookTitle ,BookId = bk.BookId, StockLogValue=bksty.StockLogValue, SaleTotal = trs.Sum(c => c.TransactQty), GiftTotal = trs2.Sum(c => c.TransactQty), SalesCount = trs.Count(), GiftCount = trs2.Count() });
        return query.AsEnumerable(); 
    }
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Linq to entities? Please show (essential parts of) the classes, because you should try to do this with navigation properties in stead of joins.

Comment: @GertArnold I have added the classes thanks

Comment: Why don't you have navigation properties, like `Book.StockLogs`?

Comment: The truth is I have not thought of that : I have created navigation Id for books in stocklogs now will that make it simpler  to eliminate the outer joins?

Comment: I have even made StockLogValue a direct property for Books no need to reference another table.  Because what I am thinking is the raw stock updates are stored in the stocks table and then the year and month is appended to the existing stocklogvalue of a particular book

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate solution to your problem is to remove the `from a in b.DefaultIfEmpty()` lines. A `join - into` [is the same as `GroupJoin`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15599143/861716), which creates collections related to the left item, i.e. collections `Transacs` belonging to a book. That's exactly what you want here.

A subsequent `from` is equivalent to a `SelectMany`, which flattens these collections again, leaving you with a flat list of book-transact rows.

So this will do what you want:

```
var query =
    (from bk in db.Books
     join tr in db.Transacts
                  .Where(a => a.TransactDate.Month == month && a.TransactDate.Year == year && a.TransactType.TransactTypeName == "sale")
        on bk.BookId equals tr.BookId into trs
     join tr2 in db.Transacts
                   .Where(a => a.TransactDate.Month == month && a.TransactDate.Year == year && a.TransactType.TransactTypeName == "gift")
        on bk.BookId equals tr2.BookId into trs2
     select new ReportViewModel
            {
               BookTitle = bk.BookTitle,
               BookId = bk.BookId, 
               StockLogValue=bksty.StockLogValue, 
               SaleTotal = trs.Sum(c => c.TransactQty), 
               GiftTotal = trs2.Sum(c => c.TransactQty), 
               SalesCount = trs.Count(), 
               GiftCount = trs2.Count() 
            });
```

I asked about navigation properties, because nearly always they make queries easier to write, since you don't need the cluncky `join`s. In your case the difference isn't that big though. If `Book` would have a navigation property `Transacts` the query could look like:

```
var query =
    (from bk in db.Books
     let sales = bk.Transacts
                   .Where(a => a.TransactDate.Month == month && a.TransactDate.Year == year && a.TransactType.TransactTypeName == "sale")
     let gifts = bk.Transacts
                   .Where(a => a.TransactDate.Month == month && a.TransactDate.Year == year && a.TransactType.TransactTypeName == "gift")
     select new ReportViewModel
           {
               BookTitle = bk.BookTitle,
               BookId = bk.BookId, 
               StockLogValue=bksty.StockLogValue, 
               SaleTotal = sales.Sum(c => c.TransactQty), 
               GiftTotal = gifts.Sum(c => c.TransactQty), 
               SalesCount = sales.Count(), 
               GiftCount = gifts.Count() 
           });
```