# Need explanation about LINQ GroupJoin syntax

Tags: linq

I am not strong in LINQ but I am trying to get familiar with `GroupJoin`

In the following code, which I am trying to understand

```
var result = authors.GroupJoin(books,
                               author => author.AuthorId,
                               book => book.AuthorId,
                               (author, booksByAuthor) => 
                                new { Author = author.Name, Books = booksByAuthor });
```

which was rewritten from this join into code

```
var result = from a in authors
             join b in books on a.AuthorId equals b.AuthorId into booksByAuthor
             select new { Author = a.Name, Books = booksByAuthor };
```

I am confused by the syntax in the `GroupJoin`. I understand that the tables authors is joined with books, but what is the meaning of the next few lines?

For example, what is the meaning of `author => author.AuthorId`, `book => book.AuthorId`? Is these two lines the equivalent of

```
on a.AuthorId equals b.AuthorId
```

?

And what is the meaning of this line:

```
(author, booksByAuthor) => new { Author = author.Name, Books = booksByAuthor }
```

I can read/understand the Join into statement but having some difficulties with the `GroupJoin`. Thanks.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15599143/861716).

Answer (score 1):

Probably you get confused because the two examples use different aliases for one and the same things. So let fix that:

```
var result = from a in authors
             join b in books on a.AuthorId equals b.AuthorId into booksByAuthor
             select new { Author = a.Name, Books = booksByAuthor };
```

and

```
var result =
    // authors join books 
    authors.GroupJoin(books,
    // on a.AuthorId equals b.AuthorId
    a => a.AuthorId, b => b.AuthorId,
    // select new { Author = a.Name, Books = booksByAuthor }
    (a, booksByAuthor) => new { Author = a.Name, Books = booksByAuthor }
);
```

Hope that helps.