# Tricky LINQ query: return string that contain substring of the max length substring

Tags: vb.net, linq

i have 2 datatables each datatable has 300,000 rows (datatables imported from 2 excel worksheets with OLEDB).

the first datatable is 'dtTosearch' and the second datatable is 'sourceDt'.

here is an example for the 2 tables:

[image: datatables example]

i need to find for each row in 'untagged' column (sourceDt) a match to each row in 'token' column (dtTosearch). the match conditions are:

1. 'site' value = 'site' value
2. 'cat' value = 'category' value
3. untagged value must contain token value
4. if all the conditions above exist for more then one match so the query must    **returen the match of the token with the maximum length**.
   **(and this is the tricky part that i didnt figure out how to perform with
   linq)**
5. this task must run in minimum process time - because its the requirement, because that's more professional and because i made a bet with friend-colleague-JAVA enthusiastic developer that .NET will run faster (plain as day (-:)

ive added the relevant parts of the code, it works fine but not in the way i want, i want to improve processing time, look at the foreach loop in linqQuery() function - i will be thankful if you help me to replace that loop by expanding my query to condition number 4, the loop operate for condition 4 because the result of **the linq query ordered by 'token' length in descending order so it will exit and return the result with the maximum row length.**

```
Private Sub startScanning()
    Dim siteNum As Double
    Dim categoryNum As Double
    Dim stringToSearchin As String

    For i = 0 To sourceDt.Rows.Count - 1
        siteNum = sourceDt.Rows(i).Item(0)
        categoryNum = sourceDt.Rows(i).Item(1)
        stringToSearchin = sourceDt.Rows(i).Item(3)
       Debug.WriteLine( linqQuery(siteNum, categoryNum, stringToSearchin) & " " &
           stringToSearchin)
    Next
End Sub

Private Function linqQuery(ByVal sitenum As Double, ByVal cat As Double,
                           ByVal stringToSearchIn As String) As String

    Dim query = From row In dtTosearch
                Where (row.Field(Of Double?)("site") = sitenum And
                row.Field(Of Double?)("category") = cat)
                Order By row.Field(Of String)("token").Length Descending
                Select New With {
                    .token = row.Field(Of String)("token")
         }


    For Each x In query
        If stringToSearchIn.Contains(x.token) Then
            Return x.token
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next

    Return ""
End Function
```

Thank you very much for your time and consideration!

Comment: hi @gnicolas i tagged also C# because its dosent matter to me if an example will be C# or VB

Comment: If pseudocode is ok:

I think you need a group join here. You want to join every record from table1 with many records from table2. 

    `var joinedTables = from r1 in table1
                       join r2 in table2
                       on new {r1.site, r1.cat , r1.untagged.Contains(r2.token)} equals new {r2.site, r2.category, true} into possibleMatches
                       select new {row1 = r1, row2 = possibleMatches.MaxBy(p => p.token.Length)}`
    
Then you have a flat ienumerable of your joined records.

Sorry about the formatting I'm on mobile.

Comment: A LINQ-join will be much faster than a For loop. The For loop variant results in comparing each row of one table to each row of the other one O(m*n). A join on the other hand uses a hash table internally reducing the costs to approximately O(n).

Comment: tnx @gnicolas i understand the concept, the problem with linq to me is that i always struggling with the syntax, i will try to implement what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C# code you can find the records you want by

```cs
from r1 in sourceDt.AsEnumerable()
join r2 in dtToSearch.AsEnumerable() 
    on new { p1 = r1.Field<int>("cat"), p2 = r1.Field<int>("Site") }
    equals new { p1 = r2.Field<int>("category"), p2 = r2.Field<int>("site") }
    into r2g
select new
{
    r1,
    p2 = (from r2 in r2g
          let token = r2.Field<string>("token")
          where token.Contains(r1.Field<string>("untagged"))
          orderby token.Length descending, token
          select r2).FirstOrDefault()
}
```

That is, first *group join* the datatables on the fields they must have in common. The `join - into` syntax makes this a group join as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15599143/861716).

Then, within a group of matching rows, the rows containing the value of `untagged` in their `token`s are filtered, and the one with the longest token is returned (also alphabetically the first one, in case there are ties on length).

Comment: thank you very much @Gert, for the code, the explanation and the the link to your answer about groupjoin, exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: This is the right answer but one small note: 
doing an orderby and then firstordefault is sorting an entire list to get a maximum (which probably doesn't matter for performance here but is worth noting). The "proper" solution is a generic extension method MaxBy like that found in moreLINQ.

Comment: @gnicholas I think that most of the times only a small list is sorted for each row, i.e. the list of joined items (4 items in the example). But as this is a speed challenge, tho OP may want to give it a try.