# Linq grouping - <k,v> where does my 'V' go?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

In the following code:

```
    var finalArticles =
        from domainArticle in articlesFoundInDomain

        join articleCategoryVersion in dbc.ArticlesCategoriesVersions
            on domainArticle.ArticleID equals articleCategoryVersion.ArticleID
        join articleCategory in dbc.ArticleCategories
            on articleCategoryVersion.CategoryID equals articleCategory.CategoryID

        where articleCategory.ParentID == 52

        group articleCategory by articleCategory.CategoryID
            into newArticleCategoryGroup
```

I understand that the group clause should be returning an IEnumerable where k is the Key, in this case CategoryID.

I think I'm misunderstanding Linq at this point because I assume that for each 'k' there should be a list of articles in 'v', but I don't understand the mechanisms or terminology or something. When I try to project this statement into a new anonymous object I don't seem to get any articles... where are they?

**Edit:** 
Okay so I've got a piece of code that is working, but unfortunately it's hitting the SQL server multiple times:

```
var articlesAssociatedWithKnowledgeTypes =
                from categories in dbc.ArticleCategories

                join categoryVersions in dbc.ArticlesCategoriesVersions
                    on categories.CategoryID equals categoryVersions.CategoryID

                join articles in articlesFoundInGivenDomain
                    on categoryVersions.ArticleID equals articles.ArticleID

                where categories.ParentID == 52 && articles.Version == categoryVersions.Version

                select new
                {
                    ArticleID = articles.ArticleID,
                    ArticleTitle = articles.Title,
                    ArticleVersion = articles.Version,
                    CategoryID = categories.CategoryID,
                    CategoryName = categories.Name
                } into knowledgeTypesFlat
                group knowledgeTypesFlat by new { knowledgeTypesFlat.CategoryID, knowledgeTypesFlat.CategoryName } into knowledgeTypesNested
                select new
                {
                    CategoryID = knowledgeTypesNested.Key.CategoryID,
                    CategoryName = knowledgeTypesNested.Key.CategoryName,
                    Articles = knowledgeTypesNested.ToList()
                };
```

I thought the ToList() on Articles would sort that out but it doesn't. But, the code works although I'm not sure if this is optimal?

Comment: `join into` is not a Join, but a GroupJoin. It's a combination of joining and grouping

Comment: Could you show how do you want to project your first query?

Comment: @Dennis_E okay fair enough, so at the end of my first example, what do I need to 'select' in order to get an IEnumerable<k,v>, or as user InBetween points out IGroup<k,v>, where K = Category and V = List of Articles associated with K?

Comment: @octavioccl what I need is to project IGrouping<k,v> where 'k' is the category (but it seems it will be the CategoryID only - although I need the name of the category too) and 'v' is the list of articles associated with it. I assumed something like 'select new { CategoryID = newArticleCategoryGroup.Key, Articles = ...}'

Comment: Sounds like you need a tutorial on LINQ. This guy explains things very nicely https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL90AF0EFFEF782D27

Comment: @Dennis_E yeah I'm running through tutorials at the moment and Jamie King is one of the lot that I'm following. Just trying to get to grips with some of the nuances in Linq. I've been doing a lot of UI work over the last few years, but getting back into C# again

Comment: @Jacques Good luck with that. I admit the `join into` / GroupJoin is a little weird. C# and LINQ are awesome, but they can be a little complicated sometimes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595289/linq-to-entities-join-vs-groupjoin/15599143#15599143. But as I said on your previous post: use navigation properties.

Answer (score 1):

The grouping returns an enumeration of `IGrouping`s. `IGrouping<K, V>` itself implements  `IEnumerable<V>`. Think of each group as an enumerable of all the members of that group plus an extra property `Key`

Comment: I'm sure it's `IGrouping<TKey,TElement>` which implements `IEnumerable<TElement>`, not `IGroup`

Comment: @inbetween I'm sure that makes perfect sense to you, but Linq is new'ish to me. I edited my post with another example that does actually work where Employees is accessible, but it's kind of obivous i.e. when I loop through the result of the query expression I have result.Department and result.Employees. How are the two usages of 'into' different?

Comment: @RenéVogt yes, fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your first query you are showing a group by and the second one is a group join, both return different results. The group by returns an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>>`. To get the result you're expecting you could group by `CategoryId` and `CategoryName` and project as I show below:

```
var finalArticles =
    from domainArticle in articlesFoundInDomain
    join articleCategoryVersion in dbc.ArticlesCategoriesVersions
        on domainArticle.ArticleID equals articleCategoryVersion.ArticleID
    join articleCategory in dbc.ArticleCategories
        on articleCategoryVersion.CategoryID equals articleCategory.CategoryID
    where articleCategory.ParentID == 52
    group articleCategory by new{ articleCategory.CategoryID,articleCategory.CategoryName}
        into g
    select new {CatId=g.Key.CategoryID, CatName=g.Key.CategoryName,Articles =g.ToList() };
```

When you need the grouped elements you can call `ToList` or `ToArray` as I did above

Comment: @octaviocci I actually tried this yesterday. Interestingly if I loop through Articles of the anonymous type I don't get an article. I seem to get back a category plus an additional property "article.ArticlesCategoriesVersions" which is of type EntitySet<Entities.ArticlesCategoriesVersions>.

Answer (score 0):

Your `finalArticles` query results in a `IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, Article>>` (assuming `CategoryID` is `int` and your articles are of type `Article`).

These `IGrouping<int, Article>` provides a `Key` property of type `int` (your `CategoryID` and also the `IEnumerable<Article>` representing the sequence of articles for that `CategoryID`.

You can turn this for example into a `Dictionary<int, List<Article>>` mapping `CategoryID`s to the lists of articles:

```
var dictionary = finalArticles.ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.ToList());
```

or to a list of categories containing articles:

```
var categories = finalArticles.Select(group => new { 
                 CategoryID = group.Key, 
                 Articles = group.ToList()}).ToList();
```

---

Update after your comment:

```
var finalArticles =
      from domainArticle in articlesFoundInDomain
      join articleCategoryVersion in dbc.ArticlesCategoriesVersions
           on domainArticle.ArticleID equals articleCategoryVersion.ArticleID
      join articleCategory in dbc.ArticleCategories
           on articleCategoryVersion.CategoryID equals articleCategory.CategoryID

      where articleCategory.ParentID == 52

      group articleCategory by new {articleCategory.CategoryID, articleCategory.Name}
      into newArticleCategoryGroup
      select new 
      { 
          CategoryID = newArticleCategoryGroup.Key.CategoryID,
          CategoryName = newArticleCategoryGroup.Key.Name,
          Articles = newArticleCateGroup.ToList()
      }
```

Comment: I would need the Category ID and Name as well as the list of articles. It looks like you're using Extension methods, could this not be tacked directly onto my query expressions?

Comment: @Jacques updated my answer. I'm not so experienced with query syntax and more often use method syntax. Note that query syntax is only a _subset_ of method syntax and gets translated into methods by the compiler.