# Subtract two tables with linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

This is my first post and I hope you can help me. I didn't find an answer so here I'm:

I created this query in SQL and it works.

```
string consultaSQL =
                    @"SELECT a.GastosEstudio - ISNULL(SUM(b.GastosEstudioR),0) AS restagastos, a.Articulo - ISNULL(SUM(b.ArticuloR),0) AS restaarticulo, a.Honorarios - ISNULL(SUM(b.HonorariosR),0) AS restahonorarios, a.IVAHonorarios - ISNULL(SUM(b.IVAHonorariosR),0) AS restaivahonorarios FROM deudores a LEFT JOIN recibos b ON a.DNI=b.DNI WHERE a.DNI = @DNI GROUP BY a.GastosEstudio, a.Articulo, a.Honorarios, a.IVAHonorarios";
```

Now I need to do the same but in LINQ. Basically: I have two tables (`deudores` and `recibos`). In `deudores` I have the debt with the different concepts (columns):

```
gastos, articulo, honorarios, ivahonorarios
```

In the table `recibos` I insert the receipts with the same columns.

The SQL query sums the receipts and subtracts the debt. The closest I get in LINQ was this:

```
var query = (from d in bd.deudores                         
             join r in bd.recibos on d.DNI equals r.DNI
             where d.DNI == DNI
             group d by d.DNI into g
             select new
                     {
                         DNI = g.Key,
                         articulo = g.Max(x => x.Articulo) - g.Sum(x => x.ArticuloR),
                         gastos = g.Max(x => x.GastosEstudio) - g.Sum(x => x.GastosEstudioR),
                         honorarios = g.Max(x => x.Honorarios) - g.Sum(x => x.HonorariosR),
                         ivah = g.Max(x => x.IVAHonorarios) - g.Sum(x => x.IVAHonorariosR),
                     });
```

The problem with this query is that if there is no receipt does not show any information (should show the initial debt)

I try with `DefaultIfEmpty` but didn't work:

```
var query = (from d in bd.deudores
             join r in bd.recibos on d.DNI equals r.DNI into Pagos
             from p in Pagos.DefaultIfEmpty()
             where d.DNI == DNI
             group d by d.DNI into g
             select new
 {
     DNI = g.Key,
     articulo = g.Max(x => x.Articulo) - g.SelectMany(x => x.recibos).Count() >= 1
        ? g.SelectMany(x => x.recibos).Sum(y => y.ArticuloR)
        : 0,
     gastos = g.Max(x => x.GastosEstudio) - g.SelectMany(x => x.recibos).Count() >= 1
            ? g.SelectMany(x => x.recibos).Sum(y => y.GastosEstudioR)
        : 0,
     honorarios = g.Max(x => x.Honorarios) - g.SelectMany(x => x.recibos).Count() >= 1
        ? g.SelectMany(x => x.recibos).Sum(y => y.HonorariosR)
        : 0,
     ivah = g.Max(x => x.IVAHonorarios) - g.SelectMany(x => x.recibos).Count() >= 1
        ? g.SelectMany(x => x.recibos).Sum(y => y.IVAHonorariosR)
        : 0
 });
```

The problem with this query is that it does not subtract it.

Any suggestion?

Thank you!

Comment: Try changing `from p in Pagos.DefaultIfEmpty()` to `from r in Pagos.DefaultIfEmpty()`

Comment: Nice, thank you. I'll try it and I leave a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You want the equivalent of an outer join, so you correctly turn to a [`GroupJoin`, or `join ... into`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15599143/861716). But the query part ...

```
 from d in bd.deudores
 join r in bd.recibos on d.DNI equals r.DNI into Pagos
 from p in Pagos.DefaultIfEmpty()
 where d.DNI == DNI
 group d by d.DNI into g
```

... does more than you want. In fluent LINQ syntax its structure is equivalent to

```
bd.deudores.GroupJoin(bd.recibos, ...)
           .SelectMany(...)
           .GroupBy(...)
```

The point is that the first `GroupJoin` creates a collection of `deudores`, each having a group of their `recibos`, that may be empty. Then the `SelectMany` flattens it into pairs of one `deudores` and one `recibos` *or null*. Subsequently, the `GroupBy` creates groups with `null` elements.

The first `GroupJoin` is all you need:

```
from d in bd.deudores
join r in bd.recibos on d.DNI equals r.DNI into g
select new
{
    DNI = d.DNI,
    articulo = d.Articulo - g.Select(x => x.ArticuloR).DefaultIfEmpty().Sum(),
    gastos = d.GastosEstudio - g.Select(x => x.GastosEstudioR).DefaultIfEmpty().Sum(),
    honorarios = d.Honorarios - g.Select(x => x.HonorariosR).DefaultIfEmpty().Sum(),
    ivah = d.IVAHonorarios - g.Select(x => x.IVAHonorariosR).DefaultIfEmpty().Sum()
});
```

By adding `DefaultIfEmpty()` it is ensured that `Sum` will return 0 when there are no elements.

Comment: Thanks!, i'll try this too.

Comment: I tried but it does not work. The first part of `select new` in the `articulo = g.Max(x => x.Articulo)` the part of `Articulo` is underlaing in a red line (i don't know how to post an image with the error)

Comment: The message is something like this (i use google translantor: `recibos` does not contain a definition for `Articulo` nor is there any extension method `Articulo` that accepts a first `recibos` type argument (is there no using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: What is the relationship between `deudores` and `recibos`? Maybe the first thing you should do is create navigation properties between them so it's possible to do the query without the (LINQ) join statement.

Answer (score 0):

@Gert Arnold: The relationship between the two tables is a column name `DNI`. In the table `deudores` is PK and in the table `recibos` is FK. Last night i tried this code and it works:

```
var query = (from d in bd.deudores 
         join r in bd.recibos 
         on d.DNI equals r.DNI into g
         where d.DNI == DNI 
         select new 
         {
          articulo = d.Articulo - g.Sum(x => x.ArticuloR) ?? d.Articulo,
          gastos = d.GastosEstudio - g.Sum(x => x.GastosEstudioR) ?? d.GastosEstudio,
          honorarios = d.Honorarios - g.Sum(x => x.HonorariosR) ?? d.Honorarios,
          ivah = d.IVAHonorarios - g.Sum(x => x.IVAHonorariosR) ?? d.IVAHonorarios
          });
```

Is it the best way to do it ?. If you want to give me your opinion will be welcome.

Regards!