# Include unrelated table in Linq to entity query

Tags: c#, linq, include, linq-to-entities, entity

I have the following simplified setup:

```
Public User
{

  //Primary key
  public int Id {get;set;}

  public string Name {get; set;}
}

Public UserInfo
{

  //Primary key
  public int Id {get;set;}

  //Foreign key to user table
  public int userKey {get; set;}
}
```

The relationship between the tables is one user to Many userInfo

I am trying to select from the `user` table and include the `userInfo` table.

I cannot do this:

```
var users = Context.user.Include(u => u.userInfos);
```

as there is no reference to the `UserInfo` table from the user table.

I can do this:

```
context.userInfo.include(x => x.user)
```

but if there are no corresponding entries in the userInfo table, this will not return any results, which is not what I want. Also, this will return one row for each userInfo, whereas I want one row for user, with a list of userInfo as a parameter.

Similarly I could join the tables like this:

```
var users = from us in Context.user
    join inf in Context.userInfo
    on us.Id equals inf.userKey
    select new //etc
```

But this will also return one row per userInfo entry, the same problem as above.

To summarise, is there a way of including this table to produce a result in the same way as the `include` function does.

I know I could adjust my setup to all me to include this, but that is not what I am asking here.

I suspect this cannot be done, but from all my googling so far I have not been able to find a definitive answer....

Comment: I guess `User` has a property `UserInfos` or something like that? (BTW, do yourself a great favor and adhere to naming conventions, like class and property names starting  with capitals).

Comment: so you are looking for left join in linq? here is a solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want one row for user, with a list of userInfo as a parameter

I assume you mean a list of userInfo as a *property*. My understanding of what you ask it that you're just looking for:

```
var users = from us in Context.user
    join inf in Context.userInfo
        on us.Id equals inf.userKey into infg
    select new
    {
        User = us,
        UserInfos = infg
    };
```

`join ... into` amounts to a [`GroupJoin`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595289/linq-to-entities-join-vs-groupjoin/15599143#15599143), i.e. a user entity joined with a group of userinfos.

Better still is to use a navigation property `user.userInfos` (reluctantly following your naming convention):

```
var users = Context.user.Include(u => u.userInfos);
```

Comment: I have edited the question to explain why I cannot use your suggested include method, but the first solution you propose works so thank you for that!!