# Use LINQ to get only the most recent JOINed item for each element

Tags: c#, linq

I have a LINQ query:

```
Elements.Join(ElementStates,
            element => element.ElementID,
            elementState => elementState.ElementID,
            (element , elementState ) => new { element, elementState })
```

OK, so each `Element` has an `ElementState` associated to it.  However there can be multiple states for each element for historical purposes, marked by a `DateModified` column.  In this query, I would like to return only the most recent `ElementState` for each `Element`.

Is such a thing possible, using LINQ?

EDIT:

Credit to Gilad Green for their helpful answer.

I have converted it to Method syntax for anyone else who would like to see this in the future:

```
Elements.GroupJoin(ElementStates,
    element => element.ElementID,
    elementState => elementState.ElementID,
    (element, elementState) => 
    new { element, elementState = elementState.OrderByDescending(y => y.DateModified).FirstOrDefault() });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GroupJoin` instead of `Join` and then retrieve the first record after ordering the group by the `DateModified`:

```
var result = from e in Elements
             join es in ElementStates on e.ElementID equals es.ElementID into esj
             select new {
                 Element = e,
                 State = esj.OrderByDescending(i => i.DateModified).FirstOrDefault()
             };
```

*The same can be implemented with method syntax instead of query syntax but in my opinion this is more readable*

For the difference between simply joining and group joining: [Linq to Entities join vs groupjoin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15595289/6400526)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about GroupJoin.  As for the syntax... my team has decided that the Method syntax is better for reasons I don't agree with, but I am following that convention.  I will try to convert this to method syntax.  Thanks again.