# LinqToEntities GroupJoin ArgumentException

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, left-join

I have the following model:

```
public class UserPage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public bool Editable { get; set; }
}

public class UserPageSetting
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int PageId { get; set; }
    public bool Published { get; set; } = true;
    public DateTime? Modified { get; set; }

    public virtual UserPage UserPage { get; set; }
}
```

I want to select all UserPages, even if UserPageSettings table does not have records with such FK .
I have the following linq:

```
        var joined = _dbContext.UserPages.GroupJoin(_dbContext.UserPageSettings, i => i.Id, o => o.PageId, (i, o) => o
           .Select(x => new UserPageSettingDto { Editable = i.Editable, Id = i.Id, Modified = x.Modified, Name = i.Name, Path = i.Path, Published = x.Published })
           .DefaultIfEmpty(new UserPageSettingDto { Id = i.Id, Name = i.Name, Path = i.Path, Published = true, Editable = true }))
           .SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```

but I get the following exception:

> ArgumentException: Expression of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[TmsApi.Core.UserPageSetting]'
>   cannot be used for return type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[TmsApi.Dto.UserPageSettingDto]'

what is wrong?

Comment: If i understood correctly, you need to add DefaultIfEmpty after your join UserPageSetting then you can select UserPageSettingDto.

Comment: This might be useful link to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595289/linq-to-entities-join-vs-groupjoin