# Lambda / Linq Left joining table(s) does not return expected result

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I created a Lambda LEFT join in my .net core 3 (preview 5) razor page application but for some reason I can't get it to work properly.

I have the following issues:

- Results from `T-SQL` and the Lambda are different
- My `Where` part in Lambda generates an error

I have the following query which I want to recreate in my application using lambda:

```
SELECT 
   ai.crArtNrLeverancier,
   pli.crartnr
FROM [tblArtikelImport] ai
LEFT JOIN tblPLInkoop pli on pli.crArtNr = ai.crArtNrLeverancier
WHERE pli.crartnr is not null
```

In `T-SQL` this results in 22241 records.

My Lambda query to get the same result set:

```
var data = await _context.TblArtikelImport.GroupJoin(_context.TblPlinkoop,
    ai => ai.CrArtNrLeverancier,
    pli => pli.CrArtNr,
    (ai, pli) => new { ArtikelImport = ai, PLInkoop = pli })
    .Where(c => c.PLInkoop.Any(cc => cc.CrArtNr != null)).ToListAsync();
```

With the `pli anonymous` type I cant select a field directly, that's why I tried to use `PLInkoop.Any`

The `WHERE` part returns the following error:

```
InvalidOperationException: Error generated for warning 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryClientEvaluationWarning: The LINQ expression 'where ([cc].CrArtNr != null)' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.'.
```

Next I tried to remove the `Where` part entirely in my Lambda statement which results in the following:

```
var data2 = await _context.TblArtikelImport.GroupJoin(_context.TblPlinkoop,
    ai => ai.CrArtNrLeverancier,
    pli => pli.CrArtNr,
    (ai, pli) => new { ArtikelImport = ai, PLInkoop = pli })
    .ToListAsync();
```

The above Lambda statement returns 32962 records while the following `T-SQL` statement (which should be the same), returns 51809 records:

```
SELECT 
       ai.crArtNrLeverancier,
       pli.crartnr
FROM [tblArtikelImport] ai
LEFT JOIN tblPLInkoop pli on pli.crArtNr = ai.crArtNrLeverancier
```

I am pretty new to Lambda in general so perhaps it is something obvious. I am using EF Core and generated the EF Core models using EF Core power tools (to reverse engineer the tables).

Comment: Why are you left-joining and then adding validation to not null. Then you can simply use inner join, or am I missing something?

Comment: Good point. The original query was different where I needed to do a LEFT JOIN, but that is no longer the case.

Comment: @TomasChabada with a regular (INNER) JOIN it works.. The expected result is correct and the `WHERE` clause works. Still wondering why it doesn't work with the `GroupJoin` though..

Comment: Not sure, but when I want to implement `left join` in code, I use `DefaultIfEmpty` method and that is translated to regular left join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Gert Arnold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/861716/gert-arnold) has written an excellent answer to a similar problem explaining how the Linq joins work:
[Linq to Entities join vs groupjoin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595289/linq-to-entities-join-vs-groupjoin)

It seems like you are missing the flattening part by using `.SelectMany()` on the Linq query.
This is described in the linked answer just above part 2.