# Linq left outer join with custom comparator

Tags: c#, linq, join

I am trying to make a `left outer join` query that also has a `custom comparator`.

I have the following lists:

```
List<ColumnInformation> list1;
List<ColumnInformation> list2;
```

These hold information about an SQL column (datatype, name, table, etc). I have overrided `Equals` for the class, and made a `operator ==` and `operator !=`.

I understand how to [make a left outer join](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5491381/1043380):

```
var leftOuterJoin = from l1 in list1
                    join l2 in list2 on l1.objectID equals l2.objectID into temp
                    from l2 in temp.DefaultIfEmpty(new { l1.ID, Name = default(string) })
                    select new
                    {
                        l1.ID,
                        ColumnName1 = l1.Name,
                        ColumnName2 = l2.Name,
                    };
```

And I understand how to make and use a custom `IEqualityComparer`:

```
public class ColumnComparer : IEqualityComparer<ColumnInformation>
{
    public bool Equals(ColumnInformation x, ColumnInformation y)
    {
        return x == y; //this uses my defined == operator
    }

    public int GetHashCode(ColumnInformation obj)
    {
        return 1; //forcing the join to use Equals, just trust me on this
    }
}

ColumnComparer cc = new ColumnComparer();
var joinedList = list1.Join(list2,
    x => x,
    y => y,
    (x, y) => new {x, y},
    cc);
```

My question is: **How can I do both a left outer join and use my comparator at the same time**?

As far as I know, the query syntax does not have a keyword for a comparator, and the extension method does not have anything for the `into` keyword.

I do not care if the result is in query syntax or extension methods.

Comment: You can override `ColumnInformations` Equals and GetHashCode as implemented in ColumnComparer.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan, I have overridden the `Equals` in `ColumnInformation`. Right now my code does not touch it. What benefit would this do (also for the GetHashCode)?

Comment: I have to say that **you can do all the things you want in LINQ** with extension methods but **you can't do some things in LINQ with the query syntax**. In fact the equivalent of `join into` in `extension methods` is `GroupJoin`.

Comment: @KingKing, `GroupJoin`, would not have guess that from the name. I would be very happy if you could provide an example.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. Try implement [IEquatable<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) in `ColumnInformation`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you do that is with a `GroupJoin` and `SelectMany` (to flatten the results):

```
ColumnComparer cc = new ColumnComparer();
var joinedList = list1
    .GroupJoin(list2,
        x => x,
        y => y,
        (x, g) => new {x, g},
        cc)
    .SelectMany(
        z => z.g.DefaultIfEmpty(),
        (z, b) => new  { x = z.x, y = b } 
    );
```

Comment: The OP said 'My question is: How can I do both a left outer join and use my comparator at the same time?'. I wonder how this answer is a response to the actual need of the OP !?

Comment: @Alireza, this does a left outer join (using the `DefaultIfEmpty()`), and uses my comparer (`cc`). This is a correct answer.

Comment: @gunr2171 Oops! Sorry, I didn't notice **'cc'**. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of Sub-Query in combination with Where:

```
var leftOuterJoin = from l1 in list1
                    select new 
                   {
                      jointList = (from l2 in list2 
                                   where l2.objectID == l1.ObjectID // <-- and you can do any other comparing logic in where clause
                                   select l2).DefaultIfEmpty(),                        
                      l1id = l1.ID,
                      ColumnName1 = l1.Name,
                      ColumnName2 = l2.Name
};
```

Comment: In the end, the `where` clause would be `l2 == l1`. I have my comparing logic in that operator method.

Comment: @gunr2171 You asked for how to involve your customized comparator to form a Join query, right? You can call whatever method returning a bool to feed the 'Where' clause. Doesn't this satisfy you?

Comment: Don't get me wrong, your answer was fine, and I was only adding a bit of clarification, but it was not wrong. I just happened to go with the other answer because it made sense for me.

Comment: @gunr2171 Ok. Thanks for clarification on the accepted answer. I didn't completely get that. Now I know it :D