# Linq join and then checking for data that was unable to be joined

Tags: c#, linq

I have a scenario where I get some data from two sources (over the web). The data comes in chunks and are continuously arriving until I end my program.
The data from the two sources are stored in two `List<T>`'s. `T` is *different* for the two lists.

I then `Join` the two lists on some parameter into a *third* type, and after joining then, I would like to look in each lists for data that was not possible to join.

The sequence is:

1. Accumulate data in lists
2. Join lists
3. Clear lists
4. Put unjoinable data in lists
5. Repeat

So far I have a pretty nice linq query centered around a `Join`, and it works nicely.
But when I come to checking if the two lists contain data that was not able to be joined, I have a linq query which essentially iterates through all three lists looking. This is a bit silly and kind of slow, so I was wondering if there is a nice way of joining data in linq while also creating a list of unjoinable data from the two lists.

Comment: Sounds like you need outer joins - similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489987/linq-full-outer-join

Comment: @davisoa The problem here, is that I need to filter out the joinable data and put in a list anyway. And then I would need to create two lists of the remaining full outer join to separate the unjoinable values into each of the corresponding lists.

Comment: I would put it all in a joined list, and then use `GroupBy` to pull out the successful joins from the unjoinable values.

Comment: FullOuterJoin saved the day!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you'd want to use [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I agree.  I'd also take a look at [intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect(v=vs.110).aspx) and [zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx) Or even [RX extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577611.aspx)

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear enough (I've now edited the q). The three lists are of different types.

Comment: The lists may be of different types, but if the composite type contains unique IDs of the two constituent lists, you can do an EXCEPT on ids

Comment: Isn't except iterating through the lists? So we end up with iteration of creating the joined lists, and the iteration for the except.

Comment: If you're trying to prevent loops I would suggest taking a look at [this](http://www.25hoursaday.com/weblog/2008/06/16/FunctionalProgrammingInC30HowMapReduceFilterCanRockYourWorld.aspx) article on implementing map and reduce functions in C#. Otherwise you're not programming in a functional language, so loops are going be everywhere or hidden from you by a library.