# Sum and Group multiple Linq Lists

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq

So here is the thing...

I got 2 tables

Table 1 : Purchase

```
id | aid | amount
1     1      5
2     3      8
3     7      2
4     1      3
```

Table 2 : Given

```
id | aid | amount
1     2      4
2     1      3
3     7      5
4     1      1
```

What I want to do is to sum the amounts of the both tables and group by **aid** field, but in different rows. So the result of these two tables would be :

Result

```
aid | sum1 | sum2
 1     8      4
 2     0      4
 3     8      0
 7     2      5
```

The LINQ is in VB.net...
What I have so far is this :

```
Dim one = From r In Purchase 
             Select r.aid, r.amount
             Group By aid
             Into total1 = Sum(amount)

Dim two = From p In Given
            Select p.aid, p.amount
            Group By aid
            Into total2 = Sum(amount)

Dim final = From p In one
            Join r In two On p.aid Equals r.aid


[ POPULATE LIST VIEW ]

For Each itm In final
   Dim X As ListViewItem
   X = lstPregledSaldo.Items.Add(itm.p.aid)
   X.SubItems.Add(itm.p.total1)
   X.SubItems.Add(itm.r.total2)
 Next
```

But this generates me Left Join and if the element with aid is not in the table one it doesn't take it in the query.. i don't know how to solve this :S

Comment: It is an inner join not a left join. If it was a left one you would be happy.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489987/linq-full-outer-join

Comment: Okay, but I need to know how to join and do the Sum operation meanwhile :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim Purchases = (From r In db.Purchase
               Select r.aid, r.amount).ToList()

Dim Given = (From p In db.Given
            Select p.aid, p.amount).ToList()


Dim aidValues = Purchases.Concat(Given).Select(Function(x) x.aid).OrderBy(Function(x) x).Distinct()

For Each a In aidValues
    Dim sumP = Purchases.Where(Function(x) x.aid = a).Sum(Function(y) y.amount)
    Dim sumG = Given.Where(Function(x) x.aid = a).Sum(Function(y) y.amount)

    Console.WriteLine("aid {0}, sum1 {1}, sum2 {2}", a, sumP, sumG)
Next
```

You can use `concat` to select the values you need from both tables (in this case a list of distinct **aid** records). and then calculate your total for each table in a loop.

Result:

```
aid 1, sum1 8, sum2 4
aid 2, sum1 0, sum2 4
aid 3, sum1 8, sum2 0
aid 7, sum1 2, sum2 5
```

Comment: I can't rate you, need reputation :S

Answer (score 0):

While this is not exactly the answer you are looking for you might be able to use [Linqer](http://www.sqltolinq.com/) or LINQpad to convert this SQL into LINQ.

```
WITH T AS (
    SELECT P.aid
          ,SUM(P.amount) As 'tp'
          ,0             As 'tg'
    FROM purchase P
    GROUP BY P.aid
  UNION
    SELECT G.aid
          ,0
          ,SUM(G.amount) 
    FROM given g
    GROUP BY g.aid
)
SELECT aid
      ,SUM(tp) AS 'Total Purchase'
      ,SUM(tg) As 'Total Given'
FROM T
GROUP BY aid
```

I have also created a test environment on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/85798/35/0).