# Add up values from two datatables into a new datatable

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, datatable, strongly-typed-dataset

I have two strongly typed Datatable (`dt1`):

```
|FirstName|LastName|Val1|Val2|
|Tony     |Stark   |34  |35  |
|Steve    |Rogers  |12  |23  |
|Natasha  |Romanoff|2   |100 |
```

and the second (`dt2`)

```
|FirstName|LastName|Val1|Val2|
|Tony     |Stark   |16  |5   |
|Bruce    |Banner  |2   |1   |
|Steve    |Rogers  |54  |40  |
```

I try to create a new Datatable where I add up the values for the persons. I need a outer join since I need all persons and the value in the second table is halved.

So the result should looks like:

```
|FirstName|LastName|Val1|Val2|
|Tony     |Stark   |42  |37.5|
|Steve    |Rogers  |39  |43  |
|Natasha  |Romanoff|2   |100 |
|Bruce    |Banner  |1   |0.5 |
```

My approach was with LINQ:

```
Dim query = 
from a in ds1.Table1
Join b in ds2.Table2
On a.FirstName + a.LastName Equals b.FirstName + b.Lastname
Select New With {
.FirstName = a.FirstName,
.LastName = a.LastName,
.Val1 = a.Val1 + b.Val1 *0.5,
.Val2 = a.Val2 + b.Val2 *0.5
}
```

But I dont get all persons with the approach. I also tried

```
Dim query = 
From a in ds1.Table1
From b in ds2.Table2
Select New With{
Key .KeyName = a.FirstName + a.LastName = b.FirstName + b.FirstName,
.Val1 = a.Val1 + b.Val1 *0.5,
.Val2 = a.Val2 + b.Val2 * 0.5
}
```

Now I get many entries for each person. Could anyone help me get this done. I dont know if there is maybe another approach without Linq to solve this.

Comment: you need [Full Outer JOIN using LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489987/linq-full-outer-join)

Comment: I'd go a for loop and a dictionary. If you really want LINQ, check this out: [LEFT OUTER JOIN in LINQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq). The key is `.DefaultIfEmpty()`, you need to do LEFT OUTER JOIN and then RIGHT OUTER JOIN, so that gives you a FULL JOIN.

Comment: [Perform a Left Outer Join by Using the Group Join Clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb918093.aspx)

Comment: An other option would be to do a union with a group by.

Comment: have you tried to apply the solution to your datatables? is it working?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will try it on monday, we have holiday today and I have no access to the database. No worries I will not forget this question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example using `group by`. The thing to consider is that before performing the `group by` and the `Sum` operation all the values in the second table must be divided by 2. I take care of that before the `.Concat`

```
var dt1 = new List<MyClass>();
dt1.Add(new MyClass { FirstName = "Tony", LastName = "Stark", Val1 = 34, Val2 = 35});
dt1.Add(new MyClass { FirstName = "Steve", LastName = "Rogers", Val1 = 12, Val2 = 23});
dt1.Add(new MyClass { FirstName = "Natasha", LastName = "Romanoff", Val1 = 2, Val2 = 100 });


var dt2 = new List<MyClass>();
dt2.Add(new MyClass { FirstName = "Tony", LastName = "Stark", Val1 = 16, Val2 = 5 });
dt2.Add(new MyClass { FirstName = "Bruce", LastName = "Banner", Val1 = 2, Val2 = 1 });
dt2.Add(new MyClass { FirstName = "Steve", LastName = "Rogers", Val1 = 54, Val2 = 40 });


var q = from a in dt1
                .Concat(
                    from b in dt2 
                    select new MyClass 
                        {
                            FirstName = b.FirstName,
                            LastName = b.LastName,
                            Val1 = b.Val1 * 0.5m,
                            Val2 = b.Val2 * 0.5m
                        })
        group a by new {a.FirstName, a.LastName}
        into g
        select new
            {
                g.First().FirstName,
                g.First().LastName,
                Val1 = g.Sum(x => x.Val1),
                Val2 = g.Sum(x => x.Val2),
            };


foreach (var s in q)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3}", s.FirstName,s.LastName,s.Val1,s.Val2);
}
```

**Result**

```
Tony Stark 42,0 37,5
Steve Rogers 39,0 43,0
Natasha Romanoff 2 100
Bruce Banner 1,0 0,5
```

Comment: Hi! Your code runs perfect. I was still looking for a left/right->fulljoin solution. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I dont care about the stupid points. You got them. It is just, all commentators above lead me to a full join solution (follow the links). I thought... ok, try it out. Btw. I dont get points for check my own answer, but I get points for checking your answer.

Comment: @ruedi Ok sorry I didn't know that. The commentators gave hints but no actual solutions. The problem with your query is the halved values so I don't think that you can make a group join before reducing the values to 50% (not in a single query at least). this is why is a very interesting question imho

Answer (score 0):

I got it now. My Solution is:

```
Dim qLeft = From a in dt1.Getdt1Info
                Group Join b in dt2.Getdt2Info
                On a.FirstName + a.LastName Equals b.FirstName + b.LastName  
                Into NewGroup = Group
                From c in NewGroup.DefaultIfEmpty
                Select New With{
                .Name = a.FirstName + ", " + a.LastName,
                .Value1 = a.Val1 + If (c is nothing, 0D, c.Val1) * 0.5,
                .Value2 = a.Val2 + If (c is nothing, 0D, c.Val2) * 0.5      
                }

Dim qRight =From a in dt2.Getdt2Info
                Group Join b in dt1.Getdt1Info  
                On a.FirstName + a.LastName Equals b.FirstName + b.LastName
                Into NewGroup = Group
                From c in NewGroup.DefaultIfEmpty
                Select New With{
                .Name = a.FirstName + ", " + a.LastName,
                .Value1 = a.val1 * 0.5 + If (c Is Nothing, 0D, c.Val1),
                .Value2 = a.val2 * 0.5 + If (c Is Nothing, 0d, c.Val2)}

Dim qFull = qleft.Concat(qRight).GroupBy(function(x) x.Name).Select(function(x) x.First)
```

I still dont know why qleft.Union(qRight) doesnt eliminate the duplicates. I solved that with the functions (s. Code).