# How to join two Lists based on common property

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Suppose I have two `Lists<myObject>` where `myObject` consists of the two properties

**Id** (of type `Int`) and

**Value** (of type `Double`)

I need to get a list out of these two lists that is made of (anonymous) objects like this:

```
Id, [Double value from List 1], [Double value from List 2]
```

So if for a given Id both lists contain a value, it should look like this example:

```
12, 21.75, 19.87
```

If one list does not contain an object with an Id that is present in the other list, the value should be *null*:

```
15, null, 22.52
```

How can I achieve that?
***Update:*** I know how I could get such a list, of course, but I'm looking for the most performant way to do it, preferrably by using some witty Linq magic.

Comment: This might be a use of the `Zip` method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/vstudio/dd267698%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: @Matthew The `Zip` method cannot be used to do this.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Not sure how optimized this is, but should suit your needs - Assuming I understood what you wanted:

```
var enumerable1 = new[]
{
    new {Id = "A", Value = 1.0},
    new {Id = "B", Value = 2.0},
    new {Id = "C", Value = 3.0},
    new {Id = "D", Value = 4.0},
    new {Id = "E", Value = 5.0},
};

var enumerable2 = new[]
{
    new {Id = "A", Value = 6.0},
    new {Id = "NOT PRESENT", Value = 542.23},
    new {Id = "C", Value = 7.0},
    new {Id = "D", Value = 8.0},
    new {Id = "E", Value = 9.0},
};

var result = enumerable1.Join(enumerable2, arg => arg.Id, arg => arg.Id,
    (first, second) => new {Id = first.Id, Value1 = first.Value, Value2 = second.Value});

foreach (var item in result)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} - {2}", item.Id, item.Value1, item.Value2);
Console.ReadLine();
```

The resulting output would be something akin to:

```
A: 1 - 6
C: 3 - 7
D: 4 - 8
E: 5 - 9
```

Don't really see why you would want null values returned, unless you absolutely need to (Besides, double is not-nullable, so it would have to be the resulting combined entry that would be null instead).

Comment: Of course this won't return null for items that don't match, it simply won't return them.

Comment: I can have multiple data lists and how many list will be there,  it is not fixed. How can I implement it?

Answer (score 8):

The requirement is slightly unclear.  Do you want a Cartesian product or a join on Id?  If the latter, then this should work:

```
var result = from l1 in list1
             join l2 in list2
               on l1.Id equals l2.Id
             select new {l1.Id, Value1 = l1.Value, Value2 = l2.Value};
```

If you actually want a full outer join, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489987/linq-full-outer-join).

Answer (score 0):

---

> **Let say  tempAllocationR is list 1 and tempAllocationV is List2 **

---

```
var tempAllocation = new List<Object>();
    if (tempAllocationR.Count > 0 && tempAllocationV.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (TempAllocation tv in tempAllocationV)
                        {
                            var rec = tempAllocationR.FirstOrDefault(tr => tr.TERR_ID == tv.TERR_ID && tr.TERR == tv.TERR && tr.Team == tv.Team);
                            if (rec != null)
                            {
                                rec.Vyzulta = tv.Vyzulta;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                tempAllocationR.Add(tv);
                            }

                        }
                        tempAllocation = tempAllocationR;
                    }}
```