# Combine values from 2 object lists based on on common variable

Tags: c#, linq, arraylist

I have two lists: List a, List b

```
var a1= new A
{
  Name = "XYZ",
  Id = "123"
};
var a2= new A
{
  Name = "UVW",
  Id = "567"
};
var a = new List<A>()
{
    a1,
    a2
};

public class A
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string Id{ get; set; }
}


var b1= new B
{
  Location = "US",
  Id = "123"
};
var b2= new B
{
  Location = "IN",
  Id = "567"
};
var b = new List<B>()
{
    b1,
    b2
};

public class B
{
    public string Location{ get; set; }
    public string Id{ get; set; }
}
```

Notice that Id is common in both A and B classes. The final goal is to have a list that contains values of members from both A and B classes:

```
var output = new List<AB>()
{
  ab1,
  ab2
}

public class AB
{
    public string Id{ get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
}
```

Or update List a to include values from List b?

How would I do that in C#?

Comment: If you describe your actual goal it might help. What are you trying to achieve by doing this? I feel like you're over-complicating a rather simple problem.

Comment: Maybe show some sample input and output of what you want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to join two Lists based on common property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25645679/how-to-join-two-lists-based-on-common-property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=netcore-3.1) to get common data based on `Id` and populate `AB`, like the following code :

```
var output = aList.Join(bList,
    a => a.Id,
    b => b.Id,
    (a, b) => new AB
    {
        Id = a.Id,
        Location = b.Location,
        Name = a.Name
    }).ToList();
```

**Demo**

```
foreach(var item in output)
{
   Console.WriteLine($"Id:{item.Id}, Name : {item.Name}, Location:{item.Location}");
}
```

**Result**:

```
Id:123, Name : XYZ, Location:US
Id:567, Name : UVW, Location:IN
```

Demo in dotnetfiddle : https://dotnetfiddle.net/3ZbK6c

I hope you find this helpful.