# Combining two Lists of an Object into one

Tags: c#, list, generic-list

I am currently developing an application that requires this senario.

Assuming I have this object

```
public class ObjectItem
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public int Name {get;set;}
   public int Sex {get;set;}
   public int Age {get;set;}
   public string Complexion {get;set;}
}
```

If we now have two lists of this object

```
var studentWithAge = new List<ObjectItem>
                  {
                    new ObjectItem {Id = 1, Name = "John", Age = 2},
                    new ObjectItem {Id = 2, Name = "Smith", Age = 5},
                    new ObjectItem {Id = 3, Name = "Juliet", Age = 7},
                  };

var studentWithSexAndComplexion = new List<ObjectItem>
                       {
                          new ObjectItem {Id = 1, Name = "John", Sex = "Male", Complexion = "fair"},
                          new ObjectItem {Id = 2, Name = "Smith", Sex = "Male", Complexion = " "},
                          new ObjectItem {Id = 3, Name = "Juliet", Sex = "Female", Complexion = "Blonde"},
                          new ObjectItem {Id = 4, Name = "Shittu", Sex = "Male", Complexion = "fair"},
                       };
```

I want to merge these two lists into just one. The end result should look like this.

```
var CompleteStudentData=new List<ObjectItem>
{
   new ObjectItem{Id=1,Name="John",Sex="Male", Complexion="fair",Age=2},
   new ObjectItem{Id=2,Name="Smith",Sex="Male", Complexion=" ", Age=5},
   new ObjectItem{Id=3,Name="Juliet",Sex="Female", Complexion="Blonde", Age=7},
   new ObjectItem{Id=4,Name="Shittu",Sex="Male", Complexion="fair", Age=0},
}
```

How do i achieve this? Using `Union` to merge the two list does not produce the desired result. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: [AddRange()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: This looks like an outer join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's possible that your collections will not have a 1-to-1 correspondence, you would have to do a full outer join.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489987/linq-full-outer-join) for how you can compose it that way.

Here's one way you can get similar results.

Collect all the keys (the ids) from both collections, then perform a left join with each of the collections, then combine the results.

```
var ids = studentWithAge.Select(s => s.Id)
    .Union(studentWithSexAndComplexion.Select(s => s.Id));
var query =
    from id in ids
    from sa in studentWithAge
                    .Where(sa => sa.Id == id)
                    .DefaultIfEmpty(new ObjectItem { Id = id })
    from ssc in studentWithSexAndComplexion
                    .Where(ssc => ssc.Id == id)
                    .DefaultIfEmpty(new ObjectItem { Id = id })
    select new ObjectItem
    {
        Id = id,
        Name = sa.Name ?? ssc.Name,
        Sex = ssc.Sex,
        Age = sa.Age,
        Complexion = ssc.Complexion,
    };
```

Comment: This answer perfectly solves my problem. So i have marked this has the correct answer.

Comment: I've made a slight adjustment to the query, the left join in query syntax is needlessly complex. I've replaced it with an equivalent query.

Comment: @frenchie: I tried your answer, but it left out the 'ObjectItem' with ID=4 from the list. That's the reason i did not accept it as the right asnwer. However, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Ah yes, didn't see the lists were of different sizes!

Answer (score 4):

```
var result = StudentWithAge.Join(StudentWithSexAndComplexion, 
                                 sa => sa.Id,
                                 ssc => ssc.Id,
                                 (sa, ssc) => new ObjectItem
                                 {
                                    Id = sa.Id,
                                    Name = sa.Name, 
                                    Age = sa.Age, 
                                    Sex = ssc.Sex, 
                                    Complexion = ssc.Complexion
                                 }).ToList();
```

Or, avoiding creation of new objects:

```
var result = StudentWithAge.Join(StudentWithSexAndComplexion, 
                                 sa => sa.Id,
                                 ssc => ssc.Id,
                                 (sa, ssc) => 
                                 { 
                                    sa.Sex = ssc.Sex; 
                                    sa.Complexion = ssc.Complexion; 
                                    return sa;
                                 }).ToList();
```

And if you want to add students presented only in the second list, than also:

```
result.AddRange(StudentWithSexAndComplexion.Where(ssc => !StudentWithAge.Any(sa => sa.Id == ssc.Id)));
```

Comment: Due to the nature of the ObjectItem and the contents of the two lists, could be better to join by Name and not Id.

Answer (score -1):

.Net has a function which is concatenating collections:

var concatenatedCollection = StudentWithAge.Concat(StudentWithSexAndComplexion).ToList();

```
        var StudentWithAge = new List<ObjectItem>()
        {
            new ObjectItem{Id=1,Name="John",Age=2},
            new ObjectItem{Id=2,Name="Smith",Age=5},
            new ObjectItem{Id=3,Name="Juliet",Age=7},   
        };

        var StudentWithSexAndComplexion = new List<ObjectItem>()
        {
            new ObjectItem{Id=1,Name="John",Sex="Male", Complexion="fair"},
            new ObjectItem{Id=2,Name="Smith",Sex="Male", Complexion=" "},
            new ObjectItem{Id=3,Name="Juliet",Sex="Female", Complexion="Blonde"},
            new ObjectItem{Id=4,Name="Shittu",Sex="Male", Complexion="fair"},
        };
        var concatenatedCollection = StudentWithAge.Concat(StudentWithSexAndComplexion).ToList();
```