# Performing GroupBy and Union using LINQ to fetch records

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, group-by, union

Here's the situation.

I am trying to perform a `Union` between two queries using LINQ. I have applied `GroupBy` in both queries, using anonymous types. I dont know exactly, but probably the usage of anonymous type is leading me to this issue where I am unable to perform that Union operation. It shows me exception like this :

> 'System.Linq.IQueryable' does not contain a
>   definition for 'Union' and the best extension method overload
>   'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Union(System.Linq.ParallelQuery,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' has some invalid
>   arguments

Here is the query :

```
var records = (from o in _context.Table1
                       join q in _context.Table2 on o.UserId equals q.UserId
                       group new { o, q }
                       by new { o.Name, o.Date, o.IsDone, o.IsDl, o.DateChanged, o.UserId, q.FirstName, q.LastName } into data
                       select new
                       {
                           NameP = data.Key.Name,
                           Date = data.Key.Date,
                           IsDone = data.Key.IsDone,
                           IsDl = data.Key.IsDl,
                           DateDone = data.Key.DateChanged,
                           Name = data.Key.FirstName +" "+ data.Key.LastName
                       }).Union(
                            from i in _context.Table1
                            where i.UserId == null
                            group i by new {o.Name, o.Date, o.IsDone, o.IsDl, o.DateChanged, o.UserId} into newData
                            select new
                            {
                                NameP = newData.Key.Name,
                                Date= newData.Key.Date,
                                IsDone = newData.Key.IsDone,
                                IsDl = newData.Key.IsDl,
                                DateDone = ' ',
                                Name = ' '
                            }).ToList();
```

What I am trying to achieve here is to get records of both cases, when `UserId` is null as well as when its not null using group by since records are repeated.

Any suggestions or guidance here on what I am doing wrong are appreciated.

Comment: Make sure that the two anonymous types have the same data type for all proprties.. the only ones I can speculate on are the date ones.. Maybe the first `DateDone` is actually a `DateTime` type and you are setting the sencond one to a `string`...

Comment: Its because you are using anonymous type. Try creating dummy result class and try. or you can try full outer join. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489987/linq-full-outer-join

Comment: @MichaelCoxon - I get your point. It should be a date. Let me try it this way.

Comment: @MichaelCoxon - It worked Michael. I just made a couple of changes and it got to work. Many Thanks.

Comment: I have added my comment as an answer. Please accept it so that others can find it. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the two anonymous types have the same data type for all proprties.

The only ones I can speculate on are the date ones. Maybe the first `DateDone` is actually a `DateTime` type and you are setting the second one to a `string`...

```
var records = (from o in _context.Table1
               join q in _context.Table2 on o.UserId equals q.UserId
               group new { o, q }
               by new 
               { 
                   o.Name, 
                   o.Date,  
                   o.IsDone,  
                   o.IsDl,  
                   o.DateChanged,  
                   o.UserId,  
                   q.FirstName,  
                   q.LastName  
               } into data
               select new
               {
                   NameP = data.Key.Name,
                   Date = data.Key.Date,
                   IsDone = data.Key.IsDone,
                   IsDl = data.Key.IsDl,
                   DateDone = data.Key.DateChanged,
                   Name = data.Key.FirstName +" "+ data.Key.LastName
               }).Union(from i in _context.Table1
                        where i.UserId == null
                        group i by new 
                        {
                            o.Name,
                            o.Date, 
                            o.IsDone, 
                            o.IsDl, 
                            o.DateChanged, 
                            o.UserId
                        } into newData
                        select new
                        {
                            NameP = newData.Key.Name,
                            Date = newData.Key.Date,
                            IsDone = newData.Key.IsDone,
                            IsDl = newData.Key.IsDl,
                            DateDone = new DateTime(0),
                            Name = ' '
                        }).ToList();
```