# Merge 2 lists based on one property and concatenate other properties

Tags: c#, linq, join, ienumerable, sql-to-linq-conversion

```
IList<MyObject> ob1 = {new MyObject {Id = "1", Items = {BananaObject1, BananaObject2}}}  
IList<MyObject> ob2 = { new MyObject {Id = "1", Items = {BananaObject2, BananaObject3}},  
new MyObject {Id = "2", Items = {BananaObject3, BananaObject3}}}
```

I want to merge the 2 lists such that the resulting list would be

```
IList<MyObject> ob2 = { new MyObject {Id = "1", Items = {BananaObject1, BananaObject2, BananaObject3}},
new MyObject {Id = "2", Items = {BananaObject3, BananaObject3}}}
```

So since the id of the first item of the 2 lists were the same, they became one, and one of their property is concatenated.
I can do a for loop to achieve this, but I am looking for a neat best performance linq expression for this.

thank you

Comment: If the `Items` in one `MyObject` already contain a duplicate (like in the case of `ob2[1].Items` containing a duplicate of `BananaObject3`), do you want to keep the duplication?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ - Full Outer Join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489987/linq-full-outer-join)

Comment: I don't want to keep the duplication, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Concat` the lists together, `GroupBy` Id property, `SelectMany` to get the merged list of items:

```
ob1.Concat(ob2)
   .GroupBy(o => o.Id)
   .Select(g => new MyObject() 
   { 
      Id = g.Key, 
      Items = g.SelectMany(o => o.Items ).Distinct().ToList()
   });
```

Comment: I think you should use `Concat` here, not `Union`. There's not going to be any deduplication unless the same `MyObject` is added twice.

Comment: As per the question `g.SelectMany(o => o.Items ).Distinct().ToList()`

Comment: I agree with both of the above comments.

Comment: Right, both comments included in the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [MoreLINQ](https://github.com/fsateler/MoreLINQ):

```
obj1.FullGroupJoin(obj2, 
  a=>a.Id,
  b=>b.Id,
  (id,a,b)=>new {id=id,Items=a.Items.Union(b.Items)},
  new {id=-1, Items=new List<string>()}, //Default for left side
  new {id=-2, Items=new List<string>()});//Default for right side
```

Comment: Sorry, I guess FullGroupJoin hasn't made it into the main branch yet, but here's the code: https://github.com/fsateler/MoreLINQ/blob/full-outer/MoreLinq/FullGroupJoin.cs

Comment: Another answer is available here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489987/linq-full-outer-join