# Merging 2 lists of different objects into a third list of a different type?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm building an API wrapper for a third party API that translates their objects into business domain objects that can be used for other processing. In this case, I need to take 2 different objects `Contact` and `User` and merge them into a single list of objects called `UserContacts`. I'm matching these objects based on their `Email` property, and if there is no matching elements, a new one is inserted.

Here are my current objects and methods, I'm just trying to figure out if there's a better/faster method.

```
public class ContactUser : IUser
{
    public string SalesForceUserId { get; set; }
    public string SalesForceContactId { get; set; }
    public string ZendeskId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

private List<IUser> MergeContactsAndUsers()
{
    var sfContacts = SalesForceCache.Contacts.Data;
    var sfUsers = SalesForceCache.Users.Data;

    var newUsers = sfUsers.Select(user => new ContactUser
    {
        SalesForceUserId = user.Id, 
        Name = user.Name, 
        FirstName = user.FirstName, 
        LastName = user.LastName, 
        Email = user.Email
    }).Cast<IUser>().ToList();

    foreach (var contact in sfContacts)
    {
        var tmp = newUsers.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Email == contact.Email);
        if (tmp != null)
        {
            tmp.SalesForceContactId = contact.Id;
        }
        else
        {
            var newUser = new ContactUser
            {
                SalesForceContactId = contact.Id,
                Name = contact.Name,
                FirstName = contact.FirstName,
                LastName = contact.LastName,
                Email = contact.Email
            };

            newUsers.Add(newUser);
        }
    }

    return newUsers;
}
```

Comment: Looks like a left join.

Comment: Use a linq Join.  See following webpage : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: But will a join work when I'm trying to do an update OR insert? I only want to update 1 field if there's a matching email, otherwise I want to add it.

Comment: This seems to be more of a _full outer join_ problem, where a record can exist on the left, right, or both sides.  There's no built-in functionality in LINQ to do [full outer joins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489987/linq-full-outer-join).

Comment: Looks like I'll just have to stick with what I have then. I'm dealing with a little over 50,000 records in each list, so it can be a bit intensive, but I can change the scope of the implementation to increase performance I'm sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace your current implementation with `Join` you can have something like this:

```
private List<IUser> MergeContactsAndUsers()
{
    var sfContacts = SalesForceCache.Contacts.Data;
    var sfUsers = SalesForceCache.Users.Data;

    var leftJoinResults =
            sfUsers.Join(
                sfContacts,
                u => u.Email,
                c => c.Email,
                (u, c) => new ContactUser()
                {
                    SalesForceContactId = c.SalesForceContactId,
                    SalesForceUserId = u.Id,
                    Name = u.Name,
                    FirstName = u.FirstName,
                    LastName = u.LastName,
                    Email = u.Email
                }).Cast<IUser>().ToList();

    var rightJoinResults =
        sfContacts
            .Where(c => !leftJoinResults.Select(nu => nu.SalesForceContactId).Contains(c.Id))
            .Select(c => new ContactUser
            {
                SalesForceContactId = c.Id,
                Name = c.Name,
                FirstName = c.FirstName,
                LastName = c.LastName,
                Email = c.Email
            });

    leftJoinResults.AddRange(rightJoinResults);
    return leftJoinResults;
}
```

But because `Join` is only a left join (and you need right join as well) it still requires an additional query to get missing contacts (the query to get `rightJoinResults`).

It's more of an alternative implementation with use of `Join`. Without proper measurements it's hard to tell whether it's faster.