# SQL to LINQ convertion with full outer join

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

```
SELECT* FROM Event FULL OUTER JOIN Booking ON Event.eventId = Booking.eventId
WHERE(Booking.userId = 3) AND (Booking.bookingId IS NULL) 
OR (Event.eventId IS NULL) 
OR (Booking.eventId IS NULL)
```

This is what i have converted so far however i have encounter an error at ***"&& bookings.bookingId == null"***

The error message is ***" Operator  '&&' cannot be applied to operands of  type 'int' and 'bool"***

How do you fix it?

```
            User student = (User)Session["user"];
        var db = new EMS.Models.dbEMSEntities();
        IQueryable<Event> query =  from events in db.Events
                                   join bookings in db.Bookings
                                   on events.eventId equals bookings.eventId
                                   where bookings.userId = student.userId 
                                   && bookings.bookingId == null || events.eventId == null || bookings.eventId == null
```

Comment: I guess first you need to place bookings.bookingId == null || events.eventId == null || bookings.eventId == null in parenthesis like && (bookings.bookingId == null || events.eventId == null || bookings.eventId == null)

Comment: your `bookings.bookingId` is not nullable, try to change the property to `int?` or change the filter to `&& bookings.bookingId == 0`

Comment: bookings.userId = student.userId  and this should be bookings.userId == student.userId . "== " you need to use

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489987/linq-full-outer-join/13503860#13503860

Answer (score 1):

```
where bookings.userId = student.userId && bookings.bookingId == null || events.eventId == null || bookings.eventId == null
```

is being evaluated as

```
where bookings.userId = (student.userId && bookings.bookingId == null) || events.eventId == null || bookings.eventId == null
```

Because of this, (int)userId && (bool)(bookingId == null) is comparing an `int` against a `bool` which violates the language
Make sure you use "==" as an evaluation and not the  assignment "=".

Answer (score 0):

```
   User student = (User)Session["user"];
        var db = new EMS.Models.dbEMSEntities();
        IQueryable<Event> query =  from events in db.Events
                                   join bookings in db.Bookings
                                   on events.eventId equals bookings.eventId
                                   where (bookings.userId == student.userId)
                                   && (bookings.bookingId == null) || (events.eventId == null) || (bookings.eventId == null)
```

Comment: I have tried your method, thank you it solve the error message however it did not return any output would you have any idea why?

Comment: The output will be dependent now on the data, from the intention of the query it looks like that you are looking for students who haven't made a booking for any events, but their userID must still exist in the bookings table..it's possible within the data that this condition does not exist!

Comment: Can you send the table structure and sample data.
Then only i can figure out what's the issue.

Comment: @Phill Yes there is data existing when i tried the query