# LEFT JOIN three tables and SUM in LINQ

Tags: linq, sum, left-join

I have three tables:

- products purchased (RecordEntered as A)
- products sold in the country (SoldInCountry as B)
- products sold outside the country (SoldOutCountry as C)

[image]

Each record in A could be:

- entered and not yet sold
- entered and sold only in the country
- entered and sold only out of the country
- entered and sold in the country and also outside the country

I started grouping the pieces in table B like so:

```
SELECT        
A.IdRecord, A.Qty, sum(isnull(B.Qty,0)) AS Expr1
FROM            
RecordEntered AS A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
SoldInCountry AS B ON A.IdRecord = B.IdRecord
group by A.IdRecord, A.Qty
```

But I do not know how to go on.

I would like a query to show me how many pieces I still have in stock.
Like this:

```
A.Qty - (SUM(ISNULL(B.Qty, 0)) + SUM(ISNULL(C.Qty, 0)))
```

I wrote an example in SQL, but the goal is LINQ:

```
from a in _ctx.....
  where .....
  select...
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't easy to do a full outer join in LINQ (see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43669055/2557128) but you don't need that to solve this:

```
var numInStock = from item in RecordEntered
             select new {
                 item.Code,
                 Qty = item.Qty - (from sic in SoldInCountry where sic.IdRecord == item.IdRecord select sic.Qty).SingleOrDefault() -
             (from soc in SoldOutCountry where soc.IdRecord == item.IdRecord select soc.Qty).SingleOrDefault()
             };
```

I assumed there would only be one sold record of each type for an item, if there could be more than one, you would need to `Sum` the matching records:

```
var numInStock = from item in RecordEntered
             select new {
                 item.Code,
                 Qty = item.Qty - (from sic in SoldInCountry where sic.IdRecord == item.IdRecord select sic.Qty).DefaultIfEmpty().Sum() -
             (from soc in SoldOutCountry where soc.IdRecord == item.IdRecord select soc.Qty).DefaultIfEmpty().Sum()
             };
```