# How to Join two dictionary collections linq query

Tags: c#, linq

My first data collection is like this:

```
IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> firstSourceData;
```

Items are like this:

```
new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    ["id"] = 1,
    ["name"] = "some",
    ["age"] = 30
}
```

And my second data is another dictionary collection:

```
IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> secondSourceData;
```

Items are like this:

```
new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    ["id"] = 1,
    ["sales"] = 58,
    ["age"] = 30
}
```

These two data comes from different sources and I will create a single dictionary collection that does not contain duplicated values. Only Id key is standart for Dictianaries and other properties may be change.

```
IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> joined;

new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    ["id"] = 1,
    ["sales"] = 58,
    ["name"] = "some",
    ["age"] = 30
},
```

How can I do this with LINQ lambda expressions? (And is there any problem if sources length difference)

Comment: So you want to join by id?

Comment: yes join by id.

Comment: @Bookmaster: and every dictionary contains the id-key?

Comment: Yes contains id key, it is standart.

Comment: Joined dictioanry collection will not contain duplicated items.

Comment: Any reason why data is stored in a dictionary instead of a class?

Comment: @GiladGreen Because property names may be changed in some requests. So only id parameter key does not change. So I will join collecitons by id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you are looking to do:

- Merge the two collections of dictionaries.
- Group items by the "id" key-value.
- For each group you have multiple dictionaries so use `SelectMany` to flatten and then `GroupBy` on the key. Now you can recreate the dictionaries - `ToDictionary`. Notice that you might have keys repeating themselves so that is why the nested `GroupBy` and for the value select the one you want. Here I just used `FirstOrDefault`

So:

```
var result = firstSourceData.Concat(secondSourceData)
                .GroupBy(item => item["id"])
                .Select(group => group.SelectMany(item => item)
                                      .GroupBy(item => item.Key)
                                      .ToDictionary(key => key.Key, 
                                                    value => value.FirstOrDefault().Value));
```

---

This is the result:

```
new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    ["id"] = 1,
    ["sales"] = 58,
    ["name"] = "some",
    ["age"] = 30
},
new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    ["id"] = 2,
    ["sales"] = 58,
    ["age"] = 30
}
```

For this test case:

```
var firstSourceData = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>
{
    new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        ["id"] = 1,
        ["sales"] = 58,
        ["age"] = 30
    },
    new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        ["id"] = 2,
        ["sales"] = 58,
        ["age"] = 30
    }
};

var secondSourceData = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>
{
    new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        ["id"] = 1,
        ["name"] = "some",
        ["age"] = 30
    }
};
```

Comment: `.ToDictionary(key => key.Key, value => value.FirstOrDefault().Value)` is worked for me. Thanks

Comment: @bookmarker - ops true :) Otherwise the value is `KeyValuePair<string,object>`. Corrected

Comment: Can we do this without using id key. Can you join all, witout duplicates? So all properties will insert in new dictionary.

Comment: @bookmarker - what is the output you want? Still a collection of dictionaries?

Comment: yes collection of dictionary. Join dictionary but not duplicated.

Comment: @bookmarker - join dictionaries but how? If you want to "join" you need a key to join by

Comment: For example get first Dictionary properties of collections and create a new dictionary. But duplicated pairs will not contain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151958/discussion-between-gilad-green-and-bookmarker).

Comment: @bookmarker That is a follow-up question and should be asked in a separate question. If you post one you can tag me and I will be happy to help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Join` like this

```
from dict1 in firstSourceData
join dict2 in secondSourceData
on dict1["id"] equals dict2["id"]
select dict1.Concat(                                      //concatenates 2 dictionaries together
          dict2.Where(kv => !dict1.ContainsKey(kv.Key))   //chooses non-repeating keys
       ).ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value)       //gets a new dictionary from that
```

If the lengths of the sources are different `join` will only select these dictionaries, whose `id`s are in the first source. If you want to get all `id`s, regardless whether you have data from both sources, you can use `DefaultIfEmpty`

```
from dict1 in firstSourceData
join tempDict2 in secondSourceData
on dict1["id"] equals tempDict2["id"] into joined
from dict2 in joined.DefaultIfEmpty(new Dictionary<string, object>()) //make a new dictionary if there's none
select dict1.Concat(
          dict2.Where(kv => !dict1.ContainsKey(kv.Key))
       ).ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value)
```

If you want dictionaries from both regardless of `id`s refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489987/linq-full-outer-join) question.

Comment: Zip doesn't join by Id but by index. OP wants a flattened version where the collection containsone dictionary for every id and with all collected properties that belong to this id and were found in all dictionaries.

Comment: well, op hasn't mentioned anything like that :)

Comment: but you make assumptions that were never mentioned, OP has just said that he wants one dictionary for every id which also contains all other "properties"(key-value pairs) that belong to that ID and was collected from all dictionaries in both sequences. The only thing that is static is that every dictionary contains the id-key.

Comment: What if one source contains id's that are not in the other? This approach excludes them.

Answer (score -1):

You can do Union:

```
Dictionary<string,object> dict1 = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        dict1.Add("id", 1);
        dict1.Add("name", "Some");
        dict1.Add("age", 30);

        Dictionary<string, object> dict2 = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        dict2.Add("id", 1);
        dict2.Add("sales", 58);
        dict2.Add("age", 30);

        Dictionary<string, object> dict3 = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        dict3 = dict1.Union(dict2).ToDictionary(c => c.Key, c => c.Value);
```

Resulting values are:

```
[0] = {[id, 1]}
[1] = {[name, Some]}
[2] = {[age, 30]}
[3] = {[sales, 58]}
```

Comment: Not `Dictionary<string, object>` it s collection `IEnumerabl<Dictionary<string, object>> `