# c# datatable join and select all columns from both table

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I need to join two datatable's and select all values from both table because d1 columns are dynamic i have tried with below code and getting the join value but when i select it shows in 2 DataRows it should be in one row

```
        DataTable dtRtn = new DataTable();

        var result = from d1 in dtFormData.AsEnumerable()
                     join d2 in dtResponderDetails.AsEnumerable()
                     on d1.Field<string>("ResponderId") equals d2.Field<string>("EmployeeId")
                     select new { d1,d2};
```

I need both d1 and d2 joined result to be copied to dtRtn table

**Edit**

I have searched but there is not straight forward answer for and all answers shows how to select specific columns

Please help thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ - Full Outer Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489987/linq-full-outer-join)

Answer (score -1):

You will need to first dynamically add the columns from `dtFormData` and `dtResponderDetails` to `dtRtn`. Then you can iterate through the results of your LINQ query and create new `DataRow` objects for each.

Here is a quick stab at the necessary code you would need to add to what you currently have:

```
// Step 1: Add all columns from your two DataTables to dtRtn
// (with a prefix to avoid naming collisions)
DataTable dtRtn = new DataTable();
CopyColumns(dtFormData, dtRtn, "FormData.");
CopyColumns(dtResponderDetails, dtRtn, "ResponderDetails.");

// Step 2: Build a collection containing all of the values for this result
var numFormColumns = dtFormData.Columns.Count;
var numResponderColumns = dtResponderDetails.Columns.Count;
foreach(var row in result) {
    var targetRow = new List<object>();
    PopulateRows(row.d1, numFormColumns, targetRow);
    PopulateRows(row.d2, numResponderColumns, targetRow);
    // Pass the values in as an array, which will convert it to a new DataRow
    dtRtn.Rows.Add(targetRow.ToArray());
}

//...

private void CopyColumns(DataTable sourceTable, DataTable targetTable, string rowPrefix)
{
    foreach (DataColumn column in sourceTable.Columns)
    {
        var rowName = String.Format("{0}{1}", rowPrefix, column.ColumnName);
        targetTable.Columns.Add(rowName, column.DataType);
    }
}

void PopulateRows(DataRow sourceRow, int numColumns, List<object> targetRow)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < numColumns; i++) {
        targetRow.Add(sourceRow[i]);
    }
}
```