# How would one create summary columns in query results using Linq-to-SQL?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

Let's say we have these tables:

```
CAR
ID  Name
1   Mustang
2   Taurus

CAR_PART
ID   CAR_ID   PART_NUMBER
1    1        M772
2    1        A443
3    2        Z889

CAR_COLOR
ID     CAR_ID  COLOR_NAME
1      1       Red
2      1       Blue
3      2       Yellow
```

We need to use Linq-to-SQL to get this result:

```
CAR_ID   CAR_NAME   CAR_PART_LIST     CAR_COLOR_LIST
1        Mustang    M772,A443         Red,Blue
```

How would this be accomplished?  I have a new class created with the result column names, and figure a `select new MyClass{};` at the end would be good, but am not sure how to handle the multiple groupings for the `CAR_PART_LIST` and `CAR_COLOR_LIST` columns.

Any ideas?

---

edit: here is what I have so far:

```
from car in db.CAR
join part in db.CAR_PART on car.ID equals part.CAR_ID
join color in db.CAR_COLOR on car.ID equals color.CAR_ID
where car.ID = 1
select new MySearchResult{
     CAR_ID = car.ID,
     CAR_NAME = car.Name,
     CAR_PART_LIST = ?,
     CAR_COLOR_LIST = ?
}

public class MySearchResult{
    public int CAR_ID { get; set; }
    public string CAR_NAME { get; set; }
    public string CAR_PART_LIST { get; set; }
    public string CAR_COLOR_LIST { get; set; }

    public MySearchResult() { }
}
```

Comment: Actually, it turns out group join is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Using the obvious `String` extension method:

```
public static string Join(this IEnumerable<string> s, string sep) => String.Join(s, sep);
```

You can compute the answer by using group join on each related table:

```
var ans = from car in db.CAR
          join part in db.CAR_PART on car.ID equals part.CAR_ID into partj
          join color in db.CAR_COLOR on car.ID equals color.CAR_ID into colorj
          where car.ID == 1
          select new MySearchResult {
              CAR_ID = car.ID,
              CAR_NAME = car.Name,
              CAR_PART_LIST = partj.Select(p => p.PART_NUMBER).Join(","),
              CAR_COLOR_LIST = colorj.Select(c => c.COLOR_NAME).Join(",")
          };
```

Comment: Where would one put this extension method? (in the Controller, or elsewhere?)

Comment: You can always just replace the extension method with a call to `String.Join`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have foreign keys set up for db.CAR_PART and db.CAR_COLOR?  If so, that linq-to-sql will automatically give you properties for the joins.  So, it becomes:

```
var q = from car in db.Car
where car.ID == 1
select new MySearchResult
{
    CAR_ID = car.ID,
    CAR_NAME = car.Name,
    CAR_PART_LIST = String.Join(",", car.CAR_PARTs.Select(cp=>cp.PART_NUMBER))
    CAR_PART_LIST = String.Join(",", car.CAR_COLORs.Select(cp=>cp.COLOR_NAME))
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no foreign keys (it's a long story, but just not going to be possible).  I wonder if there is a way to do this without foreign keys?

Answer (score 1):

I writed it here [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/N3MP59) please check it out:

```
    var q = from car in cars
    join part in carparts on car.ID equals part.CAR_ID  into parts
    join color in carcolors on car.ID equals color.CAR_ID into clrs
    where  car.ID == 1

 select new MySearchResult{
 CAR_ID = car.ID,
 CAR_NAME =  car.Name,
 CAR_PART_LIST =  String.Join(",",parts.Select(p => p.PART_NUMBER)),
 CAR_COLOR_LIST = String.Join(",",clrs.Select(c => c.COLOR_NAME))};

        foreach (var item in q)
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3}",
                item.CAR_ID,
                item.CAR_NAME,
                item.CAR_PART_LIST,
                item.CAR_COLOR_LIST);
```

Answer (score 1):

So you have a table of `CarParts`, where every `CarPart` has a `CarId` and a `PartNumber`; and you have a table of `CarColours`, where every `CarColour` has a `Carid` and a `ColourName`.

I assume you do not support invisible cars, so every car has at least one part, and one colour.

You want a sequence of all `CarIds`, each `CarId` with the `CarName`, a list of all `CarParts` belonging to this `CarId`(= that have this `CarId` as foreign key) and a list of all `ColourNames` belonging to this `CarId` (again using the foreign key.

To do this, first we get all `CarIds with their CarParts` and all `CarIds with their ColourNames`, then we can `Join` the results on common `CarId`.

If you think there might be cars without parts or without colours, you need to do a 'Full outer Join' instead of a normal Join. This is not part of standard LINQ, but you can write the extension function yourself. See [LINQ Full Outer Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489987/linq-full-outer-join/13503860)

After the join on common CarId, we Join the result with your Cars on CarId

```
var partsGroupedByCarId = carParts.GroupBy(     // make groups of carParts
    carPart => carPart.CarId);                  // with common CarId as Key

var coloursGroupedByCarId = carColours.GroupBy( // make groups of carColours
    carColour => carColour.CarId);,             // with common CarId as Key

var joinResult = partsGroupedByCarId.Join(      // Join the two groups
    coloursGroupedByCarId,
    partGroup => partGroup.Key,                 // from each group of parts take the key (= CarId)
    colourGroup =>                              // from each group of colours take the key (= CarId)
    (partGroup, colourGroup) => new             // when they match make a new object
    {
        CarId = partGroup.Key,                  // with the common CarId
        CarParts = partGroup                    // all partNumbers of the car with CarId
           .Select(item => item.PartNumber),
        CarColours = colourGroup                 // all colourNames of the car with carId
            .Select(item => item.ColourName),
    });
```

Finally a Join of the Cars with all their Colours and Parts:

```
var result = Cars.Join(joinResult,    // Join all cars with the joinResult
    car => Id,                        // from every car take the id
    joinedItem => joinedItem.CarId,   // from every joinedItem take the CarId
    (car, joinedItem) => new          // for every car with its matching joinedItem
    {                                 // make a new object
         Id = car.Id,
         Name = car.Name,
         Parts = joinedItem.CarParts.ToList(),
         Colours = joinedItem.CarColours.ToList(),             
    });
```

TODO: consider creating one big LINQ statements. As all statements use deferred execution I don't think this will improve efficiency. It certainly will decrease readability.