# Full outer Join in LINQ optimized for unique keys

Tags: c#, performance, linq

Presume these two ordered sequences (the elements are unique):

```
var outer = new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'other' };
var inner = new char[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'altro' };
```

The desired result is the Full Outer Join:

```
{ 'a', 'a' }
{ 'b', 'b' }
{ 'c', 'c' }
{ 'other', '' }
{ '', 'altro' }
```

The Full Outer Join can be achieved in LINQ in this way (it's an answer on SO): [LINQ - Full Outer Join](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13503860/196210)

But this solution doesn't takes in account that the elements from both sequences are **unique**. How can the algorithm be optimized?

Comment: More efficiently than what? Also, what is the unique key?

Comment: Than the normal Linq implementation which doesn't know the keys are unique. If I'm wrong please tell me.

Comment: Show your "normal" LINQ implementation please

Comment: Why JOIN?  Just get unique list of two lists.

Comment: @Revious; So the fourth column is the key column and it's always unique? What is the desired result?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I've improved the question. However probably you are right.. but I'm sorry that this community has an extremely rigid format which doesn't allow for constructive questions.. I think a lot of work has to be done still.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: done. I get one list from a database and it's made of many records. The other is just one, from a "template".

Comment: Easy. Just change all `ToLookup()`'s into `ToDictionary()`'s. Also skip creation of the `HashSet` of keys and `UnionWith()` the `Select()`'ed keys directly instead.

Comment: If the two sequences are ordered by the unique keys, then full outer join is simple merge ordered sets operation - linear time and no additional space.

Comment: If you are doing a search by keys of a database from two lists,  combining the keys first and then doing a search of the database is more efficient then doing two joins.  I'm not looking at the simple issue of just combining the keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [referenced answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489987/linq-full-outer-join/13503860#13503860) I tried something that doesn't create `Lookup`'s but `Dictionary`'s instead.

IMHO that's the only thing you can cut that will actually save some time.

Skipping creation of the `HashSet` (as proposed in my rushed comment) is not an option as this will lead to the duplication of all joined pairs.

```
public static class Extensions {
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> FullOuterJoin<TA, TB, TKey, TResult>(
        this IEnumerable<TA> a,
        IEnumerable<TB> b,
        Func<TA, TKey> selectKeyA,
        Func<TB, TKey> selectKeyB,
        Func<TA, TB, TKey, TResult> projection,
        TA defaultA = default(TA),
        TB defaultB = default(TB),
        IEqualityComparer<TKey> cmp = null) {

        cmp = cmp ?? EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default;
        var adict = a.ToDictionary(selectKeyA, cmp);
        var bdict = b.ToDictionary(selectKeyB, cmp);

        var keys = new HashSet<TKey>(adict.Keys, cmp);
        keys.UnionWith(bdict.Keys);

        var join = from key in keys
                   let xa = adict.GetOrDefault(key, defaultA)
                   let xb = bdict.GetOrDefault(key, defaultB)
                   select projection(xa, xb, key);

        return join;
    }

    public static T GetOrDefault<K, T>(this IDictionary<K, T> d, K k, T def = default(T)) 
        => d.TryGetValue(k, out T value) ? value : def;
}
```