# How to speed up the comparison of many fields using IEqualityComparer?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq

I have a list of `AE_AlignedPartners` items in the db, which I retrieve with:

```
List<AE_AlignedPartners> ae_alignedPartners_olds = ctx.AE_AlignedPartners.AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

Than, I got and serialize a new list (of the same object type) with JSON:

```
List<AE_AlignedPartners> ae_alignedPartners_news = GetJSONPartnersList();
```

Than I'm getting the intersections of both:

```
var IDSIntersections = (from itemNew in ae_alignedPartners_news
                        join itemOld in ae_alignedPartners_olds on itemNew.ObjectID equals itemOld.ObjectID
                        select itemNew).Select(p => p.ObjectID).ToList();
```

Now, due of these intersections, I need to check if some records has been changed, checking many fields, and than add to a "monitoring" list of updates. Here's the code:

```
IList<AE_AlignedPartners> ae_alignedPartners_toUpdate = new List<AE_AlignedPartners>();
foreach (var item in IDSIntersections)
{
    var itemOld = ae_alignedPartners_olds.First(p => p.ObjectID == item);
    var itemNew = ae_alignedPartners_news.First(p => p.ObjectID == item);

    if (itemOld.Field1 != itemNew.Field1 ||
        itemOld.Field2 != itemNew.Field2 ||
        itemOld.Field3 != itemNew.Field3 ||
        itemOld.Field4 != itemNew.Field4 ||
        itemOld.Field5 != itemNew.Field5 ||
        itemOld.Field6 != itemNew.Field6 ||
        itemOld.Field7 != itemNew.Field7 ||
        itemOld.Field8 != itemNew.Field8 ||
        itemOld.Field9 != itemNew.Field9)
    {
        AE_AlignedPartners toUpdate = mapper.Map<AE_AlignedPartners, AE_AlignedPartners>(itemNew);
        toUpdate.ID = itemOld.ID;

        ae_alignedPartners_toUpdate.Add(toUpdate);
    }
}
```

Which is extremely slow (~4 minutes in release with ~70k records).

Recently I've discovered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54458988/how-to-except-specifing-another-key-or-faster-way-to-differences-two-huge-lis) the `IEqualityComparer`, which really speed up the procession of comparisons.

Can I take advantage of it in this case? Or which are a valid optimization?

I wouldn't use the suggested `FullOuterJoin`, since this will mean lots of refactoring right now (I'll do it in the next project, promise).

Any tips? Thanks

Comment: The assumption that it's the equality comparisons specifically that cause the perf problem seems unwarranted. Have you profiled it to see what's actually taking the most time? It could be anything from the acual DB I/O to excessive memory allocations to the repeated `.First()` calls doing linear searches over large collections -- the comparisons would be way down on my list of likely candidates.

Comment: You've imeplemnted *nested loops* `foreach (...) {..First(...)}`: and so you have `O(N ** 2)` time complexity `70k * 70k ~ 5e9` loops which is slow. Let's turn `ae_alignedPartners_olds` and `ae_alignedPartners_news` into a *dictionary* with `ObjectID` key

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: can you show an example?

Comment: `ObjectID` is an `int`?

Comment: @Rango: no its a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A custom `IEqualityComparer<AE_AlignedPartners>` would be nice, but not because it improves performance, it needs to do the same comparison. But because encapsulating the logic there  makes it more maintainable, readable and reusable. You could use it for many LINQ methods.

What is slow is that you always search the old and the new item via `ObjectId` in the `foreach`-loop.

You don't need to select the common `ObjectID` of both, if you have already joined the old and the new, just store the whole instances in an anonymous type:

```
var intersections = from itemNew in ae_alignedPartners_news
                    join itemOld in ae_alignedPartners_olds on itemNew.ObjectID equals itemOld.ObjectID
                    select new { New = itemNew, Old = itemOld };

foreach(var x in intersections)
{
    var itemOld = x.Old;
    var itemNew = x.New;
    // ... 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have *nested loops* implementation

```
// O(N) : Loop over IDSIntersections
foreach (var item in IDSIntersections)
{
    // O(N) : Again, loop over ae_alignedPartners_olds
    var itemOld = ae_alignedPartners_olds.First(p => p.ObjectID == item);
    var itemNew = ae_alignedPartners_news.First(p => p.ObjectID == item);
    ...
```

In the worst case you are going to have `O(N) * O(N) = O(N**2)` time complexity;  billions of loops: `70k * 70k ~ 5e9`. Let's get rid of *inner loops* with a help of *dictionaries*:

```
// O(N)
var dictOld = ae_alignedPartners_olds
  .GroupBy(p => p.ObjectID) // ObjectID should be a int, string or provide good GetHashCode()
  .ToDictionary(chunk => chunk.Key,
                chunk => chunk.First());

// O(N)
var dictNew = ae_alignedPartners_news
  .GroupBy(p => p.ObjectID) 
  .ToDictionary(chunk => chunk.Key,
                chunk => chunk.First());

// O(N)
foreach (var item in IDSIntersections)
{
   // O(1) : no loops when finding value by key in dictionary
   var itemOld = dictOld[item];      
   var itemNew = dictNew[item];
   ...
```

Now we are going to have about `3 * O(N)` loops: `3 * 70k ~ 2e5`