# How to do full outer join 2 data tables

Tags: c#, linq

DataTable1

```
LoginId LoginName SCount
1       Mohit     20
3       Riya      25
```

DataTable2

```
LoginId  LoginName ECount
2        Smita     11
3        Riya      13
```

I want to show result like this

```
LoginName  Scount  Ecount Total
Mohit      20      0      20
Smita      0       11     11
Riya       25      13     38
```

in sql I am doing like this

```
select LoginId,LoginName,Scount,Ecount,(Scount+Ecount) as Total
  from
  (
      select
      CASE WHEN t1.LoginId is null THEN  t2.LoginId ELSE t1.LoginId END as LoginId,
      CASE WHEN t1.LoginName is null THEN  t2.LoginName ELSE t1.LoginName END as LoginName,
      CASE WHEN t1.SCount is null THEN  0 ELSE t1.SCount END as Scount,
      CASE WHEN t2.ECount is null THEN  0 ELSE t2.ECount END as Ecount
      FROM [table2] t2
      full outer join [table1] t1
      on t1.LoginId = t2.LoginId
  )
  A
  order by LoginId
```

How to do in C#

I tried like this

```
DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();

DataTable UserCount1 = new DataTable();
DataTable UserCount2 = new DataTable();

// Assigning value to datatable 

if (ds != null)
{
     UserCount1 = ds.Tables["UserCount1"];
     UserCount2 = ds.Tables["UserCount2"];
}

var LinqResult = 
     from dataRows1 in UserCount1.AsEnumerable()
     join dataRows2 in UserCount2.AsEnumerable()
     on dataRows1.Field<string>("LoginId") equals dataRows2.Field<string>("LoginId") into lj
     from r in lj.DefaultIfEmpty()
     select dtResult.LoadDataRow(new object[]
     {
         dataRows2.Field<string>("LoginName"),
         r == null ? 0 : r.Field<int>("SCount"),
         r == null ? 0 : r.Field<int>("ECount")
     }, false);
```

How to do full outer join in C#.I am new to linq.How to identify whether it is right or left .

Comment: Maybe this can help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq

Comment: You can use my full outer join extension methods from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43669055/2557128). You may also find my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) helpful. There is no query syntax for full outer join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Union` for the `left` and the `right join` :

try the code snippet :

```
var leftJoin = from dataRows1 in UserCount1.AsEnumerable()
              join dataRows2 in UserCount2.AsEnumerable()
              on dataRows1.Field<string>("LoginId") equals dataRows2.Field<string>("LoginId") into lj
              from r in lj.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new
              {
                 LoginName = dataRows1.Field<string>("LoginName"),
                 SCount = dataRows1.Field<int>("SCount"),
                 ECount = r?.Field<int>("ECount") ?? 0,
                 Total = dataRows1.Field<int>("SCount") + (r?.Field<int>("ECount") ?? 0)
              };

var rightJoin = from dataRows2 in UserCount2.AsEnumerable()
                join dataRows1 in UserCount1.AsEnumerable()
                on dataRows2.Field<string>("LoginId") equals dataRows1.Field<string>("LoginId") into rj
                from l in rj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new
                {
                   LoginName = dataRows2.Field<string>("LoginName"),
                   SCount = l?.Field<int>("SCount") ?? 0,
                   ECount = dataRows2.Field<int>("ECount"),
                   Total = dataRows2.Field<int>("ECount") + (l?.Field<int>("SCount") ?? 0)
                };

var result = leftJoin.Union(rightJoin);
```

i hope that will help you out

Comment: Note that this is not the same as a full outer join.

Comment: An incorrect answer only occurs if there are duplicate rows in either table, or `LoginId` and `LoginName` aren't always mapped 1 to 1. Assuming those are true, this will provide a correct answer.