# how to use select right after outer join keyword

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

The code SQL below is what I want to do but it's not working. Eventually I will convert that to LinQ query but for now, I just want to know how to make this works. I have one line matching in *TemplateFields* when I put *where templateId =29* table and I want to full outer join with the *TemplateAvailableFields*. How can I use select right after full outer join?

```
select 
    ta.TemplateAvailableFieldId, ta.FieldName, ta.Required 
from 
    TemplateAvailableFields as ta 
full outer join 
    (select DefaultValue, DisplayOrder 
     from TemplateField 
     where TemplateId = 29) as t on ta.TemplateAvailableFieldId = t.TemplateAvailableFieldId;
```

Comment: There is no full outer join concept in LINQ. Also, its not clear what you mean by "select right after full outer join", or "not working". And I think you should use SQL tags, not LINQ.

Comment: Does this answer your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489987/linq-full-outer-join