# LINQ Implementation of Query with Multiple Joins

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design, clean-architecture

Hi fellow developers I am planning to have DDD design and I am planning to create a LINQ/C# version of the SQL script provided to me (please see below).
May I ask if the LINQ implementation at the last section of this post is correct? Or may I request for your suggestions what's the best way to implement it.

Thanks in advance

**SQL Script**

```
if object_id('tempdb..#tempHistory') is not null drop table #tempHistory;

select * into #tempHistory from Table_tempVwHistory raterView
where raterView.PremiumChange != 0

select r.Id,r.Name, amt.Description as AmountType,coalesce(txn.amount,0) as BillingAmount, coalesce(rtr.amount,0) as RaterAmount from
(
    select id,Name,AmountTypeId,sum(premiumchange) amount from #tempHistory
    inner join AmountSubType ats
    on ats.id = StepAlias
    group by id,Name, ats.AmountTypeId
) rtr
full join
(
    select t.Id, ats.AmountTypeId, sum(td.Amount) amount from [Transaction] t
    inner join TransactionDetail td
    on t.id = td.TransactionId
    inner join AmountSubType ats
    on ats.id = td.AmountSubTypeId
    where AmountTypeId != 'TF'
    group by t.Id, ats.AmountTypeId
) txn
on rtr.Id = txn.Id and rtr.AmountTypeId = txn.AmountTypeId
inner join risk r
on r.id = rtr.Id or r.id = txn.Id
inner join AmountType amt
on amt.id = rtr.AmountTypeId or amt.id = txn.AmountTypeId
where coalesce(rtr.amount,0) != coalesce(txn.amount,0) and abs(coalesce(rtr.amount,0) - coalesce(txn.amount,0)) > 1
```

Here is my **LINQ implementation** in .NET Core 3

```
public async Task<List<TransactionMismatchDetails>> GetMismatchedTransactions()
{
    var tempHistory = await _context.Table_tempVwHistory 
        .Where(x => x.PremiumChange != 0)
        .ToListAsync();
    var amountSubTypes = await _context.Set<AmountSubType>()
        .ToListAsync();

    var rtr = (from r in tempHistory
               join ats in amountSubTypes on r.StepAlias equals ats.id
               group r by new { r.Id, r.Name, ats.AmountTypeId } into g
               select new
               {
                   g.Key.id,
                   g.Key.Name,
                   g.Key.AmountTypeId,
                   amount = g.Sum(x => x.PremiumChange)
               }).ToList();

    var txn = await (from t in _context.Set<Transaction>()
               join td in _context.Set<TransactionDetail>() on t.Id equals td.TransactionId
               join ats in _context.Set<AmountSubType>() on td.AmountSubTypeId equals ats.Id
               where ats.AmountTypeId != AmountType.TransactionFee.Id
               group td by new { t.Id, ats.AmountTypeId } into g
               select new
               {
                   g.Key.Id,
                   g.Key.AmountTypeId,
                   Amount = g.Sum(x => x.Amount)
               }).ToListAsync();

    return (from r in rtr
                  join t in txn on new { r.Id, r.AmountTypeId } equals new { t.Id, t.AmountTypeId } into rt
                  from t in rt.DefaultIfEmpty()
                  join risk in _context.Set<Risk>() on r.Id equals risk.id 
                  join amt in _context.Set<AmountType>() on r.AmountTypeId equals amt.Id
                  where r.Amount != t.Amount && Math.Abs(r.Amount - t.Amount) > 1
                  select new TransactionMismatchDetails
                  {
                      RiskId = risk.Id,
                      PolicyNumber = risk.Name,
                      AmountType = amt.Description,
                      BillingAmount = t != null ? t.Amount : 0,
                      RaterAmount = r.Amount
                  }).ToList();
}
```

Then is it okay if those logic inside the **GetMismatchedTransactions** method will be put to the Repository class or should I put some of it in the service under Application Layer.

Comment: You cannot implement effective LINQ query for this SQL, EF Core do not support temporary tables and FULL JOIN. So why not just execute this SQL via `Dapper`?

Comment: Hi @SvyatoslavDanyliv, currently we are using EF Core instead of Dapper. 
I think temp table can be omitted when implemented using LINQ.

Comment: You can use Dapper as a helper together with EF Core, it is common case. Yes, temporary table can be omitted but for `FULL JOIN` you have to use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62603994/10646316) - not tested but there are a lot similar answers on SO.

Comment: Thank you for your input @SvyatoslavDanyliv.

Comment: You can use `SqlQuery` or `ExecuteSql` to execute arbitrary SQL using efcore: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries#querying-scalar-non-entity-types