# Convert SQL to Linq with multiple joins , SUM and group by

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq

I am trying to convert an SQL query to LINQ where the query has 2 left joins and group by.

```
SELECT t1.Shop,t1.Stake, t2.Payout, t3.Anticipation FROM
    (SELECT Shop, sum(Stake) AS 'Stake' FROM Bets GROUP BY Shop) t1
  FULL OUTER join
    (SELECT Shop, SUM(Amount) AS 'Payout' FROM Transactions where TransactionType = 1 GROUP BY Shop) t2 on t1.Shop = t2.Shop
  FULL OUTER join 
    (SELECT Shop, sum(WinAmount) as 'Anticipation' from Bets where [Status] = 'W' group by Shop) t3 on t1.shop  = t3.shop
```

This is the SQL query that works and below you can see the LINQ code that I have tried but it does not work

```
var obj = (from b in _context.Bets
group b by b.Shop into betsList
join t in _context.Transactions.Where(x = >x.TransactionType == TransactionType.Acceptance) on betsList.Key equals t.Shop
group t by t.Shop into transactionsList
from t in transactionsList.DefaultIfEmpty()
join ant in _context.Bets.Where(x = >x.Status == 'W') on b.Id equals ant.Id into anticipationList
from ant in anticipationList.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new {
    Shop = betsList.Key,
    Stake = betsList.Sum(k = >k.Stake),
    Payout = transactionsList.Sum(x = >x.Amount),
    Anticipation = anticipationList.Sum(x = >x.WinAmount)
}).ToList();
```

Sample output data from the SQL query is:

[image]

Comment: [mre], a little sample for input will be nice. and a copy pastable one. an img will be a bad idea.

Comment: You can perhaps isolate your issue by trying to write in linq part of the SQL `(SELECT Shop, sum(Stake) AS 'Stake' FROM Bets GROUP BY Shop)`. => `var stakeBets = _context.Bets.GroupBy().Select()` into different variables and validate the result.  The the full outer join will be easier to write. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489987/linq-full-outer-join

Answer (score 1):

Better to divide query in small parts. This one should work, it is not FULL OUTER JOIN but, I think, with your data it may work:

```cs
var betsQuery = 
    from b in _context.Bets
    group b by new { b.Shop } into g
    select new 
    {
        g.Key.Shop,
        Stake = g.Sum(x => x.Stake)
    };

var transactionQuery = 
    from t in _context.Transactions
    where t.TransactionType == TransactionType.Acceptance
    group t by new { t.Shop } into g
    select new 
    {
        g.Key.Shop,
        Payout = g.Sum(x => x.Amount)
    };

var antisipationQuery =
    from b in _context.Bets
    where b.Status == 'W'
    group b by new { b.Shop } into g
    select new 
    {
        g.Key.Shop,
        Anticipation = g.Sum(x => x.WinAmount)
    };

var query = 
    from b in betsQuery
    join t in transactionQuery on b.Shop equals t.Shop into tg
    from t in tg.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join a in antisipationQuery on b.Shop equals a.Shop into ag
    from a in ag.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
        b.Shop,
        b.Stake,
        Payout = (double?)t.Payout,
        Anticipation = (double?)a.Anticipation
    };

var result = query.ToList();
```