# EF select many doesn't retrieve record which has no relation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many, full-outer-join

I have two tables, for example,  `Student` and `Grade`.
Those two tables have a relationship with many-to-many, so the table is `StudentGrade`.
By using the `.SelectMany` query, I can retrieve all records which have a relation.
For example,

```
var myResult = myDb.Student.SelectMany(x => x.Grade).ToList();
```

But let say I add a new record just to the `Student` table, which has no relation with `Grade`, this new record cannot be retrieved by using the query above.
How can I retrieve all data including this new one?

```
Student
Id     Name    Age
1      AAA     4
2      BBB     5
3      CCC     6
4      DDD     7

Grade
Id    Name
1     G1
2     G2
3     G3
4     G4

StudentGrade
Student    Grade
2          1
2          2
2          3
3          3

Require result:
Id     Name    Age   Grade
1      AAA     4  
2      BBB     5     G1
2      BBB     5     G2
2      BBB     5     G3
3      CCC     6     G3    
4      DDD     7
```

I found [full outer join](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5491381/9587283) would help but will it work in a many-to-many relationship?
How can I overcome this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

```
  var result = (from s in myDb.Student 
    from g in myDb.Grades 
    where !g.Select(x => x.Student).Contains(s) || g.Student == null || g.Student == s).ToList();
```

As long as I understand your question this should give you

- all Students that have grades,
- all Grades with no students,
- and all Students with no grades.
  I have not seen your models but this should help

Answer (score 0):

> var myResult = myDb.Student.SelectMany(x => x.Grade).ToList();

This query "means" retrieve all the Grades that have a Student.  If you want the Students, select Student and Include the Grades if you want.

```
var myResult = myDb.Students.Include(x => x.Grades).ToList();
```

Comment: please note that there is many-to-many table, by using include, it will not retrieve from this table ?